# How to start an Intent by passing some parameters to it?

Tags: android, constructor, android-intent

I would like to pass some variables in the constructor of my ListActivity

I start activity via this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent (this, viewContacts.class));
```

I would like to use similar code, but to pass two strings to the constructor. How is possible?

Comment: I think it would be a better question if it asked how to pass the parameters to a new Activity as well how to get the parameters once you pass them. I dont understand why we need to have 2 separate questions if you need to use both to really have any functionality anyways. (Thats why i included how to get parameters in my answer look below)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

In order to pass the parameters you create new intent and put a parameter map:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("firstKeyName","FirstKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("secondKeyName","SecondKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In order to get the parameters values inside the started activity, you must call the `get[type]Extra()` on the same intent:

```
// getIntent() is a method from the started activity
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
String firstKeyName = myIntent.getStringExtra("firstKeyName"); // will return "FirstKeyValue"
String secondKeyName= myIntent.getStringExtra("secondKeyName"); // will return "SecondKeyValue"
```

If your parameters are ints you would use `getIntExtra()` instead etc. 
Now you can use your parameters like you normally would.

Comment: How can we ensure `getIntent()` returns the intent we created in your first code snipper?

Comment: when you start an Activity you pass in an intent. This is the intent that will be returned. notice: `myIntent.putExtra("secondKeyName","SecondKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);`

Answer (score 43):

I think you want something like this:

```
Intent foo = new Intent(this, viewContacts.class);
foo.putExtra("myFirstKey", "myFirstValue");
foo.putExtra("mySecondKey", "mySecondValue");
startActivity(foo);
```

or you can combine them into a bundle first.  Corresponding getExtra() routines exist for the other side.  See [the intent topic](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) in the dev guide for more information.

Comment: Here's an example of how to get these values in the launched activity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4233898/246743

Answer (score 2):

**putExtra()** : This method sends the data to another activity and in parameter, we have to pass key-value pair.

Syntax: `intent.putExtra("key", value);`

Eg: `intent.putExtra("full_name", "Vishnu Sivan");`

`Intent intent=getIntent()` : It gets the Intent from the previous activity.

`fullname = intent.getStringExtra(“full_name”)` : This line gets the string form previous activity and in parameter, we have to pass the key which we have mentioned in previous activity.

Sample Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("firstName", "Vishnu");
intent.putExtra("lastName", "Sivan");
startActivity(intent);
```