# How do I get extra data from intent on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I send data from one activity (intent) to another?

I use this code to send data:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);
i.putExtra("id", user.getUserAccountId()+"");
i.putExtra("name", user.getUserFullName());
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Java side note: It is never a good idea to "stringify" integer like that (especially for example purposes), and unfortunately it is frequently considered a good, quick way to convert int to string in java: `user.getUserAccountId()+""`, as this would create unnecessary objects to be collected. Consider using `String.valueOf(user.getUserAccountId)`, or `Integer.toString(user.getUserAccountId)` instead.

Comment: @Andrew S Is this not the web? This is the number one result for "get data from intent"

Comment: @AndrewS  I agree with McGuile. Also, this question was posted a while ago so the answer probably wasn't as easy to find back then. And if a similar question hadn't been posted to SO yet, then it was a valid post.

Answer (score 1375, accepted):

First, get the intent which has started your activity using the `getIntent()` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use `intent.getStringExtra(String name)` method. In your case:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: from where to can i all this method ??

Comment: @adham: If you are in an activity, from within onCreate, you call `getIntent().getStringExtra("id");` to get the id string

Comment: You can get the intent which started your activity by calling `getIntent()` method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: What if the data is an image?

Comment: @Eatlon Then it all depends on how the image is represented. For example, if it's an array of bytes, you'll have to call `intent.getByteArrayExtra("image")`.

Comment: @Malcolm I'm using Picasso from square pulls the image and places it straight from its http address. Will the change the configuration at all?

Comment: @Eatlon If you have a problem with a specific library, you should create a separate question about that.

Comment: @Malcolm I got it to work, just dumped Picasso into the next class started by the activity and image appears very quickly, no problems.

Comment: @MelColm what is the difference between getExtra().getString and getStringExtra()?

Comment: @Amit None, the latter is just a shortcut to the former.

Comment: @WarungNasi49 There is the `hasExtra` method, but I'd rather null-check the returned value as it's more robust.

Comment: can i get an array list the similar way??

Comment: @ShreyasSanil Sure. The method you need to call depends on what it is an array list of. For example, there is a method `getStringArrayListExtra` for `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: What if some other activity also starts and puts extra? How do I identify which activity has started the activity and get intent of that activity only?

Comment: @MONUKUMAR `getIntent` always returns the intent that started this activity. All other intents either start new activities or arrive in `onNewIntent` of the current.

Answer (score 210):

In the receiving activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String userName;

if (extras != null) {
    userName = extras.getString("name");
    // and get whatever type user account id is
}
```

Comment: Why is this preferable over `getStringExtra?`

Comment: My guess is: if the extras can be `null`, the whole extras fetch can be skipped. By using `getStringExtra`, you basically change it to a series of `if(extras != null) { return extras.getString(name) }`. One for each `getStringExtra` you call. This option will check for `null` once and if so, it won't bother reading the `Bundle` at all. Besides that, `getStringExtra` will probably keep asking `getExtras` internally each time as well. So you simply have more calls to functions.

Answer (score 45):

```
//  How to send value using intent from one class to another class
//  class A(which will send data)
    Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, B.class);
    theIntent.putExtra("name", john);
    startActivity(theIntent);
//  How to get these values in another class
//  Class B
    Intent i= getIntent();
    i.getStringExtra("name");
//  if you log here i than you will get the value of i i.e. john
```

Answer (score 37):

## Add-up

### Set Data

```
String value = "Hello World!";
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sample_name", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

### Get Data

```
String value;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    value = bundle.getString("sample_name");
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Instead of initializing another new Intent to receive the data, just do this:

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
```

Answer (score 16):

Put data by intent:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, HomeWorkReportActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("subjectName", "Maths");
intent.putExtra("instituteId", 22);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Get data by intent:

```java
String subName = getIntent().getStringExtra("subjectName");
int insId = getIntent().getIntExtra("instituteId", 0);
```

If we use an integer value for the intent, we must set the second parameter to 0 in `getIntent().getIntExtra("instituteId", 0)`. Otherwise, we do not use 0, and Android gives me an error.

Answer (score 11):

If used in a FragmentActivity, try this:

The first page extends **FragmentActivity**

```
Intent Tabdetail = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReceivePage.class);
Tabdetail.putExtra("Marker", marker.getTitle().toString());
startActivity(Tabdetail);
```

In the fragment, you just need to call `getActivity()` first,

The second page extends **Fragment**:

```
String receive = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

Comment: Also you could use getStringExtra("name") instead of getExtras().getString("name")

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to get extra data in fragments then you can try using:

Place data using:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
```

Get data using:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
  getArguments().getString(ARG_SECTION_STRING);
  getArguments().getBoolean(ARG_SECTION_BOOL);
  getArguments().getChar(ARG_SECTION_CHAR);
  getArguments().getByte(ARG_SECTION_DATA);

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**You can get any type of extra data from intent**, no matter if it's an object or string or any type of data.

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extra != null){
    String str1 = (String) extra.get("obj"); // get a object

    String str2 =  extra.getString("string"); //get a string
}
```

and the **Shortest solution** is:

```
Boolean isGranted = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("tag", false);
```

Answer (score 7):

## Kotlin

**First Activity**

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("key", "value")
startActivity(intent)
```

**Second Activity**

```
val value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
```

**Suggestion**

Always put keys in constant file for more managed way.

```
companion object {
    val PUT_EXTRA_USER = "PUT_EXTRA_USER"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion:

Instead of using "id" or "name" in your i.putExtra("id".....), I would suggest, when it makes sense, using the current standard fields that can be used with putExtra(), i.e. Intent.EXTRA_something.

A full list can be found at *[Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)* (Android Developers).

Answer (score 2):

We can do it by simple means:

In FirstActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uid", uid.toString());
intent.putExtra("pwd", pwd.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity:

```
    try {
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
        String pwd = intent.getStringExtra("pwd");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("getStringExtra_EX", e + "");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the intent with value on First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uid", uid.toString());
intent.putExtra("pwd", pwd.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive intent on second Activity;-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String user = intent.getStringExtra("uid");
String pass = intent.getStringExtra("pwd");
```

We use generally two method in intent to send the value and to get the value.
For sending the value we will use `intent.putExtra("key", Value);` and during receive intent on another activity we will use `intent.getStringExtra("key");` to get the intent data as `String` or use some other available method to get other types of data (`Integer`, `Boolean`, etc.).
The key may be any keyword to identify the value means that what value you are sharing.
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this
// put value in intent

```
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Booked.class);
    in.putExtra("filter", "Booked");
    startActivity(in);
```

// get value from intent

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
```

Answer (score 1):

## Getting Different Types of Extra from Intent

To access data from Intent you should know two things.

- KEY
- DataType of your data.

There are different methods in Intent class to extract different kind of data types.
It looks like this

> #### getIntent().XXXX(KEY) or intent.XXX(KEY);

So if you know the datatype of your varibale which you set in otherActivity you can use the respective method.

#### Example to retrieve String in your Activity from Intent

```
String profileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("SomeKey");
```

#### List of different variants of methods for different dataType

You can see the list of available methods in Official Documentation of [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1):

> This is for adapter , for activity you just need to change mContext
>   to your Activty name and for fragment you need to change mContext to
>   getActivity()

```
 public static ArrayList<String> tags_array ;// static array list if you want to pass array data

      public void sendDataBundle(){
            tags_array = new ArrayList();
            tags_array.add("hashtag");//few array data
            tags_array.add("selling");
            tags_array.add("cityname");
            tags_array.add("more");
            tags_array.add("mobile");
            tags_array.add("android");
            tags_array.add("dress");
            Intent su = new Intent(mContext, ViewItemActivity.class);
            Bundle bun1 = new Bundle();
            bun1.putString("product_title","My Product Titile");
            bun1.putString("product_description", "My Product Discription");
            bun1.putString("category", "Product Category");
            bun1.putStringArrayList("hashtag", tags_array);//to pass array list 
            su.putExtras(bun1);
            mContext.startActivity(su);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, use this:

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val intent = Intent(context, Activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("name", "John")
intent.putExtra("data2","aaaa")
context.startActivity(intent)
```

and in Activity2:

```
val intent = intent
val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
val data2 = intent.getStringExtra("data2")
```

You can test by writing to the logcat:

```
`Log.d("A2", "Name $name $data2")`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A class to B class Data Sending 

A class:

Intent in = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
in.putExtra("Name", ""+user.getUserFullName());
startActivity(in);

B class:

String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
```