# Access intent after starting new activity android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am having an issue with something and I don't really know where to look or how to search for this, so I am asking here. Basically, I am starting a new activity from my main activity using this bit of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AlarmViewer.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And start my `AlarmViewer` class with a normal `onCreate`, that looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

So, I am trying trying to figure out how to access the intent I used to start the activity to get some extras that I put on it. Anyone have any idea how I can do that? If this has been asked before I'm sorry, wasn't really sure how to search for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the intent, use [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29).

To get your information, you use `getIntent().getExtras()` which returns an object of type [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). From that object, you can call the different `get*` methods depending on the type you have passed it from the calling activity

You can have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-fron-intent-in-android) for an example

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb, glad it was a simple fix though, thanks for your help