# Passing data between 2 activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tablet

I am programming in android for a Samsung tablet, and I have 2 activities, one of this is a list of football teams, and the other activity is their twitter, but i have a problem to pass the parameter for the first activity to the second one. I want to pass their url like a string, but i cant get it.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-fron-intent-in-android here is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("extraURL", "http://myUrl.com");
startActivity(i);
```

Then, to retrieve it in SecondActivity, in the onCreate method do:

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
String myUrl = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("extraURL");
```

Answer (score 1):

You typically launch the 2nd `Activity` from the first using an `Intent`. You can pass data to the 2nd `Activity` using the same `Intent` you use to launch it. For example,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("url", "http://url.you.want.to.pass/");
startActivity(i);
```

In the 2nd Activity, in the onCreate, you can read the data using:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String url = i.getStringExtra("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

your First Activity on click of button

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityTwo.class );
            intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra("www.google.com",true);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Receive it in ActivityTwo:-

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("www.google.com");
```