# How to pass a URI to an intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

I'm trying to pass a URI-Object to my Intent in order to use that URI
in another activity.

How do I pass a URI?

```
private Uri imageUri;
....
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

How do I use now this URI in my other activity?

```
 imageUri = extras.getString("imageUri"); // I know thats wrong ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get extra data from intent in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

you can store the uri as string

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
```

and then just convert the string back to uri like this

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
```

Comment: ok cool ... but I don't know how to store a uri as a string :(

Comment: In the code above, its converted to a string.  imageuri.toString() is converting the uri to a string for you.

Comment: @malclocke has a better solution. No need to manually convert to string and back.

Comment: You could use intent.setData(imageUri);

Comment: For a moment I was wondering what "extras" meant. In simple terms:

`intent.putExtra("imageUrl", mImageUri.toString());`

**In other activity**

`String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");`
`Uri mImageUri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);`

Comment: Now you can try [Kotlin way.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750949/2289835)

Answer (score 152):

The `Uri` class implements `Parcelable`, so you can add and extract it directly from the `Intent`

```
// Add a Uri instance to an Intent
intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri);

// Get a Uri from an Intent
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
```

You can use the same method for any objects that implement `Parcelable`, and you can implement `Parcelable` on your own objects if required.

Comment: Hint to anyone in the future: Make sure you're using `android.net.Uri` and not `java.net.URI`!

Comment: For future reference, if you're putting several extras in a Bundle object before using `intent.putExtras(bundle);`, use `bundle.putParcelable("imageUri", uri);` instead of using `intent.putExtra(...);` directly in the `Intent` object.

Comment: Arrays works too! `i.putExtra("URIList", uriList.toArray());` -> `List<Uri> myList = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("URIList");`

Comment: got this error when putting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Parcelable)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 66):

In Intent, you can directly put Uri. You don't need to convert the Uri to string and convert back again to Uri.

Look at this simple approach.

```
// put uri to intent 
intent.setData(imageUri);
```

And to get Uri back from intent:

```
// Get Uri from Intent
Uri imageUri=getIntent().getData();
```

Comment: **Warning:** The above answer/solution should not be used for local broadcasts as you may find they won't get received. For local broadcasts, it's better to use malclocke's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13981436/1617737 .

Answer (score 1):

```
private Uri imageUri;
....
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

And then you can fetch it like this:

```
imageUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
```

Answer (score 1):

here how I use it;
This button inside my **CameraActionActivity**  Activity class where I call camera

```
 btn_frag_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intenImatToSec = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intenImatToSec, REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO);
                //intenImatToSec.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                //intenImatToSec.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello From Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMG) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                Intent intentBitMap = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class);
                // aldıgımız imagi burda yonlendirdiğimiz sınıfa iletiyoruz
                ByteArrayOutputStream _bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, _bs);
                intentBitMap.putExtra("byteArray", _bs.toByteArray());
                startActivity(intentBitMap);

            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO) {
                Uri videoUrl = data.getData();
                Intent intenToDisplayVideo = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayVideo.class);
                intenToDisplayVideo.putExtra("videoUri", videoUrl.toString());
                startActivity(intenToDisplayVideo);
            }
        }
    }
```

And my other **DisplayVideo** Activity Class

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview_display_video_actvity);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        Uri myUri=  Uri.parse(extras.getString("videoUri"));
        videoView.setVideoURI(myUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use standard extra data field, you would do something like this:

```
private Uri imageUri;
....
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri.toString());
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

The documentation for Intent says:

```
EXTRA_STREAM   added in API level 1 
String EXTRA_STREAM
A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent,
used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent. 

Constant Value: "android.intent.extra.STREAM"
```

You don't have to use the built-in standard names, but it's probably good practice and more reusable.  Take a look at the developer documentation for a list of all the built-in standard extra data fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"))` was causing an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Parcelable)' on a null object reference
```

So I changed to the following:

```
intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri)
```

and

```
Uri uri = (Uri) getIntent().get("imageUri");
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**: Kotlin way:**

**Sender Activity:**

```
val mIntent = Intent(mContext, YourDestinationActivity::class.java)
mIntent.putExtra("key_pass_uri", mImageUri.toString())
startActivity(mIntent)
```

**Receiver Activity:**

```
val mImageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("key_pass_uri"))
```

Answer (score -3):

you can do like this. imageuri can be converted into string like this.

intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());