# pass uri to another activity and convert it to image

Tags: android

How to send a `uri` path of an image to another activity and convert it to image. I tried the below

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

              if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                  //file name
                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                     Intent i = new Intent(this,
                              AddImage.class);
                    i.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImage);
                    startActivity(i);
```

and get it like this

```
 String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
            imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath ));
```

Comment: Any errors you are facing  ??

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.sqlfirst.AddImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString .. this error is for uri.parse

Comment: ok then in your `onActivityResult()` method check if `data.getData()` is `null` or is returning `URI` and yes can you post your `log cat stacktrace`

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi but it is returning dataI placed a systemoutputln ,  do you another way to get the intent ? I read in another question is to get it through  inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage); but I didnt know how to do it

Comment: did you try coverting your `Uri` to `String`, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017374/how-to-pass-a-uri-to-an-intent

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi I have a question please .. how to get the uri like this  To open the content for a Uri, use openInputStream() on a ContentResolver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90088/discussion-between-satyen-udeshi-and-moudiz).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert you `URI` to String while adding to `Intent` like given below

```
i.putExtra("imagePath", selectedImage.toString());
```

and in your `NextActivity` get the `String` and convert back to `URI` like ->

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String image_path= intent.getStringExtra("imagePath"); 
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(image_path) 
imageview.setImageURI(fileUri)
```

Comment: small issue.. I think it needs to be imageview.setImageURI(fileUri).  Note: URI all caps

Answer (score 4):

1. First Activity

   ```
   Uri uri = data.getData();
   Intent intent=new Intent(Firstclass.class,secondclass.class);
   intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Second class

   ```
   Imageview iv_photo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);
   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("imageUri"));
   iv_photo.setImageURI(myUri);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

to use the returned uir from the calling activity and then set it to a imageview you can do this

```
Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(imagePath);
imageView.setImageURI(null); 
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

This is a workaround for refreshing an ImageButton, which tries to cache the previous image Uri. Passing null effectively resets it.

For converting the inputStream into a bitmap you could do this

```
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imagePath)); 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(in));
```

and then call

```
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

to set it it a imageview,
you could also check this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/08/convert-between-uri-and-file-path-and.html) for an example

hope i could help

Comment: I have a question please .. how to get the uri like this To open the content for a Uri, use openInputStream() on a ContentResolver

Comment: calling `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` will only get you an InputStream from a URI.

Comment: yes and if i did that can i convert the inmput stream into an image  with BitmapFactory ? if yes can you show me an example pleasee ?

Comment: I tried your code but I have this error .. how to solve it The method openInputStream(Uri) in the type ContentResolver is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream)

Comment: Try InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imagePath));

Answer (score 1):

in Next activity get that URI like this;

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String image_path= intent.getStringExtra("YOUR Image_URI");
```

and to convert that Image_URI to Image use Below mentioned Code

```
File imgFile = new File(image_path);
                if (imgFile.exists()) {

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            }
```

Comment: I got this error The method exists() is undefined for the type String

Comment: in next activity first get the URI from previous and store it into a string. declare a file and assign it . The use BitmapFactory then set imageView object to bitmap

Comment: I am getting nullexception on this       File imgFile = new File(image_path);
 .. is it possible in the main I am not getting intent?

Comment: means when your are sending ImagePath from previous activity your path is not coming

Comment: first check your code are you properly getting ImagePath or not.. thats why you are getting Nullpointer Exception

Comment: but why I am getting the path ? .. everything is normal in the app , clicking the button and choosing the image . please check is my code correct ?

Comment: you are clicking picture are getting image from gallery ?

Comment: please join the chat above that i have started with satyen .. i am waiting for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90089/discussion-between-android-softy-and-moudiz).

Answer (score 0):

To pass an image Uri to the next activity, you can just use `setData()` and `getData()`. There is no need to convert the Uri to anything.

#### First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Second Activity

```
// get Uri
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

// decode bitmap from Uri
if (uri == null) return;
try {
    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (stream == null) return;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    stream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```