# Android app crop an image and send it to another activity

Tags: android, image, bitmap, uri, crop

I'm creating an `android app` where the user `crops` the `image`, the `cropped image` is shown and then has to be sent in the `Result activity`.

The problem I have is that when I send the `image`, it sends me the **original uncropped** image.

So I wonder, am I wrong something or the image is not really **cropped**?

Can anyone help me figure out how to display the cropped `image` in the `Result activity`?

Thank you so much for your help guys.

***onActivityResult***

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                showImage(uri);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Uri sourceUri = data.getData();
                File file = getImageFile();
                Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                openCropActivity(sourceUri, destinationUri);


                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),sourceUri);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select another image");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Crop method**

```
private void openCropActivity(Uri sourceUri, Uri destinationUri) {
        UCrop.Options options = new UCrop.Options();
        options.setCropFrameColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        UCrop.of(sourceUri, destinationUri)
                .withMaxResultSize(1080, 540)
                .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                .start(this);
    }
```

**show ImageCropped on MainActivity**

```
private void showImage(Uri imageUri) {
        try {
            File file;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                file = FileUtils.getFile(this, imageUri);
            } else {
                file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            }
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select different profile picture.");
        }
    }
```

***full code MainActivity***

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE = 609;
    public static final int ONLY_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 613;

    private String currentPhotoPath = "";
    private UiHelper uiHelper = new UiHelper();
    private ImageView imageView;

    private Button vai;
    Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vai = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        vai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vaiii();
            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.selectPictureButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                if (uiHelper.checkSelfPermissions(this))
                    uiHelper.showImagePickerDialog(this, this);
        });
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    private void vaiii() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, risult.class);
        // your bitmap
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bs);
        i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
        startActivity(i);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                showImage(uri);
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            try {
                Uri sourceUri = data.getData();
                File file = getImageFile();
                Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                openCropActivity(sourceUri, destinationUri);


                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),sourceUri);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select another image");
            }
        }
    }

    private void openImagesDocument() {
        Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pictureIntent.setType("image/*");
        pictureIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            String[] mimeTypes = new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
            pictureIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pictureIntent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void showImage(Uri imageUri) {
        try {
            File file;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                file = FileUtils.getFile(this, imageUri);
            } else {
                file = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            }
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            uiHelper.toast(this, "Please select different profile picture.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionSelected(ImagePickerEnum imagePickerEnum) {

         if (imagePickerEnum == ImagePickerEnum.FROM_GALLERY)
            openImagesDocument();
    }


    private File getImageFile() throws IOException {
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM
                ), "Camera"
        );
        System.out.println(storageDir.getAbsolutePath());
        if (storageDir.exists())
            System.out.println("File exists");
        else
            System.out.println("File not exists");
        File file = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir
        );
        currentPhotoPath = "file:" + file.getAbsolutePath();
        return file;
    }

    private void openCropActivity(Uri sourceUri, Uri destinationUri) {
        UCrop.Options options = new UCrop.Options();
        options.setCropFrameColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        UCrop.of(sourceUri, destinationUri)
                .withMaxResultSize(1080, 540)
                .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                .start(this);


    }
}
```

**Activity Result**

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {

            ImageView previewThumbnail = new ImageView(this);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                    getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent()
                            .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);

            star.setImageBitmap(b);
            previewThumbnail.setImageBitmap(b);

        }
```

Comment: Instead of passing bitmap you should pass cropped image path to new activity.

Comment: that is the path uri?

Comment: Yes you need to send path to new activity

Comment: but where do I write the code with intent? in the resultActivity?

Comment: In _vaiii_ function where you are passing bitmap.

Comment: I looked at this but I can't send the uri https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348722/how-to-transfer-a-uri-image-from-one-activity-to-another/28354078

Comment: and this, but don't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664505/pass-uri-to-another-activity-and-convert-it-to-image?lq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195578/discussion-between-piyush-and-marie-hopkin).

Comment: In _showImage()_ function declare _File file;_ as global. Now in _vaiii_ function write

*Intent i = new Intent(this, risult.class);
i.putExtra("imagePath", file.getAbsolutePath());
startActivity(i);*

Comment: I can't declare it global, that is I declare it in the activity complement but when I declare it inside the function ShowImage () is not global

Comment: In main activity you need to declare it

Comment: yes I did, but it gives me the error `'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Have you removed it from _showImage()_ function ?

Comment: no, that's why it didn't work, now it works, thanks a lot.
If you answer me, the answer is correct