# how to get data from intent in the form of uri?

Tags: android

i have uri type data and i put data in intent using putExtra() but i have no idea how i get data in the uri from.

```
else if(requestCode==2){

           if (data != null) {
                   Uri uri = data.getData();

                   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),BackUp_Main.class);
                   intent.putExtra("singleImage", uri);
                   startActivity(intent);

               }
}
```

how can i get uri data in the from of uri??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a URI to an intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017374/how-to-pass-a-uri-to-an-intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save data as String and parse uri from String

Answer (score 3):

You can parse and get `Uri` like this:

```
// Add an Uri instance to an Intent
intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri);
```

Then, when you need it, just get it back this way:

```
// Get an Uri from an Intent
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a uri to String as follows:-

```
intent.putExtra("singleImage", uri.toString());
```

and then while getting intent convert String to uri back

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(extras.getString("singleImage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

when saving

```
String str = myUri.toString();
intent.putExtra("singleImage", uri);
```

and when loading

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("singleImage");
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(str);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: change uri to str becouse myUri.toString(); stored in the str

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
intent.putExtra("singleImage", uri.toString());
```