# Send and receive image in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send and receive image between the two activity using
`Intent intent = new Intent(this, second.class)` in Android.

Comment: Pass the uri to the image as an intent extra

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8017425/4684984

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a URI to an intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017374/how-to-pass-a-uri-to-an-intent)

Answer (score 0):

first you have to convert the image in byte array

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

send byte array through intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```