# How to properly put a Uri from a local file into a Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, drawable

I want my local image file (located at res/drawable) to be converted to a Uri, so I can put it into a Intent to start an Activity.

This is what I got until now:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/res/drawable/photo.jpg"));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
```

Then, the activity that receives this intent, displays the image in a ImageView. Something like this:

```
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_receive);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But instead of displaying the image, it throws an **java.io.FileNotFoundException**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No resource found for: android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/photo.jpg
```

I searched and tried other ways to get a Uri through my file:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///res/drawable/photo.jpg");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/drawable/photo.jpg");
```

But all of them returned the same error for me.

Why is my image not being recognized?

Comment: Maybe you can try the stuff in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896223/how-to-get-an-uri-of-an-image-resource-in-android

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20284270/7161261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my local image file (located at res/drawable) to be converted to a Uri, so I can put it into a Intent to start an Activity.

Resources are files on your developer machine. They are not files on the device.

> This is what I got until now

That will not work, as AFAIK there are zero Android devices with a `/res` directory off of the filesystem root, and your drawable resources would not be there anyway.

> Why is my image not being recognized?

Your third one (`android.resource` scheme) is the closest. Get rid of the `.jpg` extension.

However, many third-party apps will not recognize that scheme. And, if you are implementing the activity that is to handle this request, I have no idea why you are using `ACTION_SEND`. If your objective is to only work within your own app, skip the `Uri`, package the drawable resource ID (`R.drawable.photo`) as an `int` extra, and have your other activity use that resource ID more naturally (e.g., `setImageResource()` on the `ImageView`).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got rid of the extension .jpg and it found my image! I implemented the activity that handle it just to practice concepts that I am studying right now. Anyway, that really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should create ContentProvider for your application, which will allow you to share resources.

Try this lib, it works awesome.
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider