# Load android intent using Javascript action from HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent

I want to know if I have a web view that contains HTML design linked with some JavaScript actions at the start activity, can I open an android intent using Button defines with On-click action in the HTML ?? and if so how it's will be?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url][1]
  

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

Hope that it is what you mean

Comment: @murieldotCMR thank but i need the opposite of this action , i am in a webView and i need to open an android java activity through it

Comment: ha ok then check this new link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387999/how-to-open-webview-link-to-new-activity.

Comment: @murieldotCMR it's also takes you to a web view , i want it an android activity containing normal android xml layout not web view

Comment: Seriously?? startActivity will take you to a web view???anyway hope some one will help you