# Open Activity from WebViewClient filters

Tags: android, html, webview

I got a call a webview where ACTIVITY from a link, this activity is embedded in the same APP Calling WEBVIEW. me everything works fine but when I add the activity WebViewClient not charge me but also my links do not need to be loaded in another app, how can I make a link that is my property there will be an activity of the same app that launches the webview and also open links in the same APP

```
private class Actividad2Client extends WebViewClient {
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)

 {
     webview.loadUrl(url);
     return true; 
 }
}
```

I have this code in the manifest to activate anlace ...

```
  <activity android:name=".enlace" > 
        <intent-filter> 
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="myapp"/> 

              <data android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"/> 


        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

and the html...

```
<a href="myapp://infoextra" target="_blank">ABRIR</a>
```

¿How do I call my activity from a link and open the rest of the links in the browser. is it possible?

Comment: can you post the question in english?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387999/how-to-open-webview-link-to-new-activity