# Open activity after clicking inside webview

Tags: android, webview

How do we open an activity after clicking some specific link or button of a website which is from some website and open using webview?

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387999/how-to-open-webview-link-to-new-activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open WebView link to new activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387999/how-to-open-webview-link-to-new-activity)

Answer (score 4):

Use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to **give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new url is about to be loaded in the current WebView.** 
For more information [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

Try this it will help you:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.equals("url")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true; // Handle By application itself
    } else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```