# Received Intent doesn't contain Extras

Tags: android, android-intent

When I'm trying to pass data to another activity it for some reason gets lost. My sending activity looke like:

```
protected OnItemClickListener onArtistItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int cursor, long arg3) {
            Intent artistCardIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),  ArtistCardActivity.class);
            Artist artist = (Artist) adapter.getItemAtPosition(cursor);
            artistCardIntent.putExtra("artist_id", artist.getId());
            artistCardIntent.putExtra("tt", "tt");
            startActivity(artistCardIntent);
        };
    };
```

And while debugging I can see that artistCardIntent gets populated, however in the receiving  activity Intent i doesn't contain any extra inforamation:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.artist_card);
            Intent i = getIntent();
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS both activities extends FragmentActivity.
Thanks.

Comment: did you checked getIntent().hasExtra("artist_id"); whether its true or false in secod activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you are getting the extra information.

Check out this answer [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)

Comment: I inspect the intent object in debugger and it's extra map is null. I'm sorry for misleading

Answer (score 1):

To receive the data use getextras() method. Find the following code. i think it helps you

```
       Intent i = getIntent();
       Bundle b=i.getExtras();
       if(b!=null)
      {
      String artist= ("artist_id");
          }
```

Comment: yeah, it seems getExtras makes some adjustments to it's Intent object. In fact Phobos was talking about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

convert those values to string and try it , It will work

```
startActivity(new Intent(Home.this,galmenu.class).putExtra("page","home"));

     Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
     test=myIntent.getExtras().getString("page");
```

it is working perfectly