# getIntent().getStringExtra() shows null

Tags: android, android-intent

I m using one EditText field and one spinner. I have to pass teh results of both to the next Activity. here, reqd_bloodgroup is the spinner item, i converted into String using:
       reqd_bloodgrp = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()); inside onItemSelected() of spinner.

```
intent.putExtra("city", citySelected.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra("bloodgroup", reqd_bloodgrp);
intent = new Intent(FindDonor.this,SpecificDonor.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here when i try to display these, there's no problem. They're correctly displayed. But when i try to fetch them in SpecificDonor activity, they show null values. The code used here is:

```
String text_city,text_bloodgroup;
text_city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
text_bloodgroup = getIntent().getStringExtra("bloodgroup");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text_city + " " + "bloodgrp: " + text_bloodgroup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did u try this alternative http://stackoverflow.com/a/4233941/603744

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you must do the:

```
intent = new Intent(FindDonor.this,SpecificDonor.class);
```

before adding extras. Try with:

```
intent = new Intent(FindDonor.this,SpecificDonor.class);
intent.putExtra("city", citySelected.getText().toString());            
intent.putExtra("bloodgroup", reqd_bloodgrp);
startActivity(intent);
```