# How to check if string is empty

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have an activity 'B'. I have 2 more activities A and C. Both the activities lead to B. But i pass different Data from A and C. So while fetching

```
String dataFromA = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingA");
String dataFromC = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingC");
```

How to not get an error. I wont know from where the user is getting to activity B So how do i add an If statement or seomthing to not get an error while fetching as Either line A or C will get a NullPOinterException

Comment: Intent.hasExtra("extra") should work for you

Comment: Do you have `getIntent()` without parentheses in your code or only here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getIntent().getStringExtra() shows null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078896/getintent-getstringextra-shows-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hasExtra method to check if that String exists.

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("SomethingA")) {
    String dataFromA = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingA");
} else if (getIntent().hasExtra("SomethingC")) {
    String dataFromC = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingC");
}
```

Comment: Exactly, as I indicate at my comment!! Perfect answer @madis-r

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null){
           if (arguments.containsKey("SomethingA")) {
               String somethingA = arguments.getString("SomethingA");
               if (TextUtils.isEmpty(somethingA)){
                   // Your codes comes here
               }
           }
        }
```

Bundle (arguments) can be null if there is no data passed.

Answer (score -1):

To check if string is empty or not use below code :

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(yourString))
 {
 // String empty
 }
 else
 {
   // string not empty
  }
```

In your case you check it as :

```
  if (getIntent()!=null && getIntent().getStringExtra!=null )
    {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("SomethingA") && getIntent().hasExtra("SomethingB"))
        String dataFromA = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingA");
        String dataFromB = getIntent.getStringExtra("SomethingB");

    }
```