# Android get text typed in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an editText, How do I get the text typed in it by the user ?

example, this is my editText

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText3"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:maxLength="10">
</EditText>
```

and the user typed Hi, in my next Activity how do I make if the user typed Hi show in the next Activity Hello.. etc if the user typed How are you next activity it shows I'm fine ?

What do I use? and is it related to Database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, pick up the text in the current activity, i.e. the activity where the view hosts the `EditText` component.

```
EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
String input = txt.getText().toString();
```

Now, add it as an extra data and call your new activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("input",input);
startActivity(i);
```

In `NewActivity` inside `onCreate()` :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String input = i.getStringExtra("input");
```

and, voila, you have the entered text in the new activity.

To set this to the new `TextView` :

```
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
txtView.setText(input);
```

Comment: in `NewActivity`, change `String input = ...` to `final String input = ...`

Comment: I get error from 'i.putExtra("input",input);' Cannot refer to a non-final variable input inside an inner class defined in a different method". and if I final the string input .. the newActivity gets blank

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go would be use `Intent`'s `getExtra()` and `putExtra()` method, do a simple `String` comparison and return your results.

Here's something to get you started : [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android) and [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

But from what you have written, seems you are trying to make a chatting application wherein your application responds to the messages typed in by the user. For this, I would recommend you to use [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML). It's a long long shot, but worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your class's name is : `Main`

First declare a static public String :

```
public static String myText;
```

Now, in your OnCreate method type:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Finally, in you OnClick method type:

```
myText = getText().toString();
Intent x = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
startActivity(x);
```

Now, in your next activity you can access the String only using :

```
Main.myText
```

For exemple:

```
TextView txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
txt.setText(Main.myText);
```

Comment: same problem, the text doesn't appear in the next class