# How do I pass an exception to another activity?

Tags: android

I have a `class` which does not extend `Activity`. And in that class, I use a `try-catch` block to catch `exceptions`. How can I pass any exceptions (the `Exception e`) caught in that block to another `Activity`? My application checks with a `boolean flag` to display a `toast message`. But how do I pass this message to another activity?

```
public class AgAppHelperMethods   {

  private static AgAppHelperMethods instance = null;
  static boolean flag=true;

 public static   String[][] AgAppXMLParser( String parUrl) {



    String _node,_element;
    String[][] xmlRespone = null;
    try {
  String url = www.xyz.com
            URL finalUrl = new URL(url);


    catch (Exception e)
    {
      flag=false;
      Log.e( "CONNECTION ERROR  SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);
    } 


          public class LoginScreen extends Activity implements Serializable {


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.agapplogin);


       btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)

        {
            postLoginData();
        }

    });


           public void postLoginData()

{
               xmlRespone = AgAppHelperMethods.AgAppXMLParser( url);

        if(!AgAppHelperMethods.flag)
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error  server 
    not responding " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 catch (Exception e) {        
    flag=false;
    Log.e( "CONNECTION ERROR  SERVER NOT RESPONDING", e);

    String theException = e.getMessage();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();        
    b.putString("Exception", theException); //or you can replace theException with a custom message

    Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    nextActivity.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(nextActivity); 
    }
```

and you can receive it on the `onCreate` method of your next activity

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String error = b.getString("Exception");
    Toast.makeText(NewActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent extras to communicate extra data to another Activity:

See here: [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)
and here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html