# Error Moving Data From One Activity to Another

Tags: android

I am trying To Move Some Data From One Activity To another one.
Using Class Application

Projects Activities :

- Main_Activity.
- Second_Activity.

---

Main Activity Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ApplicationSettings application;
    private Button btn;
    private EditText txt1;
    private EditText txt2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                application = (ApplicationSettings)getApplication();
                application.setUserID(txt1.getText().toString());
                application.setUserName(txt2.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

=============================
Second Activity Code

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{

    private ApplicationSettings application;
    private TextView txt1,txt2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

           application = (ApplicationSettings)getApplication();

           txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
           txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);

           txt1.setText(application.getUserID().toString());
           txt2.setText(application.getUserName().toString());
    }
}
```

==============================
Application Class

```
public class ApplicationSettings extends Application
{


    String UserID;
    String UserName;

    public String getUserID()
    {
        return UserID;
    }
    public void setUserID(String userID)
    {
        UserID = userID;
    }
    public String getUserName()
    {
        return UserName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }   
}
```

=============================

LogCat

```
11-25 15:32:31.695: E/Trace(17282): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-25 15:32:31.960: D/libEGL(17282): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-25 15:32:31.965: D/libEGL(17282): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-25 15:32:31.965: D/libEGL(17282): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-25 15:32:31.975: D/(17282): Device driver API match
11-25 15:32:31.975: D/(17282): Device driver API version: 10
11-25 15:32:31.975: D/(17282): User space API version: 10 
11-25 15:32:31.975: D/(17282): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Wed Sep 12 17:53:53 KST 2012 
11-25 15:32:32.000: D/OpenGLRenderer(17282): Enabling debug mode 0
11-25 15:32:32.005: E/SensorManager(17282): thread start
11-25 15:32:32.010: D/SensorManager(17282): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f68078
11-25 15:32:32.075: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:37.290: D/GestureDetector(17282): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-25 15:32:37.295: D/SensorManager(17282): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f68078
11-25 15:32:37.295: D/Sensors(17282): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
11-25 15:32:37.295: I/Sensors(17282): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-25 15:32:37.295: D/SensorManager(17282): JNI - sendDelay
11-25 15:32:37.295: I/SensorManager(17282): Set normal delay = true
11-25 15:32:37.300: D/SensorManager(17282): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f69650
11-25 15:32:37.315: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:37.315: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:37.315: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:41.350: D/SensorManager(17282): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f69650
11-25 15:32:41.350: D/Sensors(17282): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
11-25 15:32:41.350: I/Sensors(17282): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-25 15:32:41.350: D/SensorManager(17282): JNI - sendDelay
11-25 15:32:41.350: I/SensorManager(17282): Set normal delay = true
11-25 15:32:41.620: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:46.200: D/SensorManager(17282): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f8b4c8
11-25 15:32:47.170: D/GestureDetector(17282): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-25 15:32:47.175: D/SensorManager(17282): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f8b4c8
11-25 15:32:47.175: D/Sensors(17282): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
11-25 15:32:47.175: I/Sensors(17282): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-25 15:32:47.175: D/SensorManager(17282): JNI - sendDelay
11-25 15:32:47.175: I/SensorManager(17282): Set normal delay = true
11-25 15:32:47.180: D/SensorManager(17282): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f8c6b8
11-25 15:32:47.210: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:47.210: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:47.210: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:50.470: D/GestureDetector(17282): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-25 15:32:50.475: D/SensorManager(17282): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f8c6b8
11-25 15:32:50.475: D/Sensors(17282): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
11-25 15:32:50.475: I/Sensors(17282): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-25 15:32:50.475: D/SensorManager(17282): JNI - sendDelay
11-25 15:32:50.475: I/SensorManager(17282): Set normal delay = true
11-25 15:32:50.480: D/SensorManager(17282): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41f8b4c8
11-25 15:32:50.490: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:50.490: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:50.490: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(17282): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-25 15:32:53.000: D/GestureDetector(17282): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-25 15:32:53.160: D/AndroidRuntime(17282): Shutting down VM
11-25 15:32:53.160: W/dalvikvm(17282): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412862a0)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test01/com.example.test01.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at com.example.test01.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:26)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-25 15:32:53.175: E/AndroidRuntime(17282):    ... 11 more
11-25 15:32:53.195: D/dalvikvm(17282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 180K, 9% free 12405K/13575K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 31ms
```

---

I need To Pass Data From the DditTexts on the main activity to the TextView in Second_activity

Thanks In Advance

Regards

Comment: Check manifest, did u add the activity ?

Comment: Thank you , Yes Actually i Forget to Add the Activity the the manifest File ,, I Added to the file ...
but now there is another error when [assing the data between activiteies

I update the second code and the logcat in the main post

Comment: @Loai.Alhalabi : now it's working or not?

Comment: what's on line 26 of the `SecondActivty.java` onCreate?

Comment: it's Working Now ,, BUT Still Have Problem to move data from activity to another activity .
Regards .

Comment: u need to add the data to the intent as intent.putExtra ...

Comment: Do You Mean The Way i Save The Data In The Application Class Is Wrong ,, Or It Can Be Easier More That Application Class ?

Comment: you are sending data from activity one to activity two right?

Comment: then u need to send the data with the intent and as I see in ur code, u r sending an empty intent

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(name,value);                startActivity(intent);

Comment: @NancyKhleif : why he use intent for sharing data between Activity because he is doing right and Application Class is also a way to share data between application components

Comment: @imran: if that way is right then its ok,, because I usually use intent to send data between activities :)

Comment: @NancyKhleif - Which Is Bettet Application Or `PutExtra()` Method ?

And How I Can Recieve A data From It In Second Activity ?

Comment: I didn't use your way before, so I don't know but from my experience Intents and putExtra is pretty easy !

Comment: @NancyKhleif If I Use Your Way ,, In SecondActivity How Can I Get The Data From The Intent ?

Comment: intent.getStringExtra("name");

Comment: check this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your Logs as :

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

means make sure you have declared `SecondActivity.class` activity in AndroidManifest as :

```
<Activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
```

if you have declared it then make sure it's in same package or have same name as you have created in `SecondActivity.java`

if you have `SecondActivity` in different Package then declare it in AndroidManifest as :

```
<Activity android:name="<FULL_PACKAGE_NAME>.SecondActivity" />
```

Comment: Thank you , Yes Actually i Forget to Add the Activity the the manifest File ,, I Added to the file ...
but now there is another error when [assing the data between activiteies

I update the second code and the logcat in the main post

Comment: where is line SecondActivity.java:26?

Comment: i mean what is line number 26 in SecondActivity.java?

Comment: `txt2.setText(application.getUserName().toString());`

Comment: are you sure you have txt2 TextView in activity_second.xml layout?

Comment: or use this.UserName = userName; and this.UserID = userID; in appliction class

Comment: It WORKS Fine After Clean The Project and add `This` before Property

Thank You So Much ,,,

Is There is another way to move data between activities without using an application Class ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20066/discussion-between-loai-alhalabi-and-imran-khan)