# Android error when compiling

Tags: android

When I run the MainActivity, it all works flawlessly, and the error shows when I start an Intent,i will not be sharing the code, since it is private, but I hope that this error message is enough.

I have encountered a problem while working with Android, here is the error I have recieved:

`04-11 00:23:42.136    9030-9030/vox.office D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-11 00:23:42.171    9030-9030/vox.office D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-11 00:23:42.171    9030-9030/vox.office D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-11 00:23:42.186    9030-9030/vox.office D/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 10
    User space API version: 10
04-11 00:23:42.186    9030-9030/vox.office D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012
04-11 00:23:42.251    9030-9030/vox.office D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-11 00:23:45.036    9030-9030/vox.office E/SensorManager﹕ thread start
04-11 00:23:45.041    9030-9030/vox.office D/SensorManager﹕ registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42d8d708
04-11 00:23:45.366    9030-9030/vox.office E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-11 00:23:45.366    9030-9030/vox.office E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
04-11 00:23:45.411    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 114K, 9% free 12434K/13639K, paused 18ms+3ms, total 44ms
04-11 00:23:49.526    9030-9030/vox.office D/SensorManager﹕ unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42d8d708
04-11 00:23:49.526    9030-9030/vox.office D/Sensors﹕ Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
04-11 00:23:49.526    9030-9030/vox.office I/Sensors﹕ sendDelay --- 200000000
04-11 00:23:49.526    9030-9030/vox.office D/SensorManager﹕ JNI - sendDelay
04-11 00:23:49.526    9030-9030/vox.office I/SensorManager﹕ Set normal delay = true
04-11 00:23:49.946    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 11% free 12609K/14023K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 31ms
04-11 00:23:49.956    9030-9030/vox.office D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-11 00:23:50.216    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 10% free 12805K/14151K, paused 13ms+14ms, total 42ms
04-11 00:23:50.366    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 11% free 12821K/14343K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 26ms
04-11 00:23:50.586    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 11% free 12845K/14407K, paused 12ms+17ms, total 59ms
04-11 00:23:50.766    9030-9033/vox.office D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 476K, 11% free 12851K/14407K, paused 5ms+8ms, total 45ms`

[image: the error]

and i got something like that [Error Moving Data From One Activity to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550961/error-moving-data-from-one-activity-to-another)

This is my problem and i got the same error, but my manifest is ok:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="vox.office" >


 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Text"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_text" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="vox.office.Text" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".showText"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_text" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="vox.office.showText" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

Intent:

```
         Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Text.class );
         intent.putExtra("nameFile", name);
         startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace? The screenshot is too small and does not show any errors

Comment: @Sunil ha sorry i edited and you can open the image in another tab.

Comment: Hmm.. there isn't any exception being thrown. How do you say you got an error? Your app should throw an exception in case there is an error? Does your app close with a not responding message? Are you catching any exceptions and not printing the stacktrace? The messages you have shown here seem to be regular log messages

Comment: @Sunil in the catch blocks : e.printStackTrace(); and yes the app close with a not responding message and i got every second this message "D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 476K, 11% free 12851K/14407K, paused 5ms+8ms, total 45ms" tnx

Comment: Can you remove the catch statement or post what the e.printStackTrace is printing? Use the debugger to see if an exception is being thrown. there has to be a relevant stack trace

Comment: @Sunil i cannot remove the catch statement and i dont know how to see what printing...what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Found similar issue Try this

[What do these Android logcat warnings mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065249/what-do-these-android-logcat-warnings-mean)

As @ArthurT said Change your build gradle to old version and try once

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'