# How to transfer data between two children activities in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, children, transfer

I have 3 Activities:
1 Parent and 2 children. Let's call them simply Activity1, Activity2a and Activity2b;

Activity2a and Activity2b are both started from Activity1. How can I transfer data from Activity2a to Activity2b through the parent? Any ideas? I think I have to use intents but don't know how.

Comment: as "matheszabi" said you can use intents. Take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types can be passed via Intent. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android) Reference I am passing via a common class, like MyApp