# get value from listview and save it in another listview in another activity

Tags: android, listview

This is my first time using eclipse for android, I want to know how can I get a value from listview and send it to another activity; something like `session` in `c#`

I want to make it so when I choose one of item in listview, and send it to another activity

```
listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
/*some code to save data in MainActivity*/
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Order.class);
startActivity(in);
}});
```

and show it in another listview in another activity;

```
array_list=new String[7];
/*array_list[0]= *something to get data from MainActivity* */
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMakanan);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**EDIT**:
this is my array string in MainActivity:

```
private String array_list[];

array_list=new String[7];
array_list[0]="Nasi Gr Seafood";
array_list[1]="Nasi Gr Magelangan";
array_list[2]="Cap Cay Goreng";
array_list[3]="Cap Cay Kuah";
array_list[4]="Sapi Cabe Hijau";
array_list[5]="Iga Lada Hitam";
array_list[6]="Sapo Tahu Ayam";
```

and I use this to put my array in ListView:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: `in.putExtra(..);` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)

Comment: what does your list contain?

Comment: @Raghunandan array string

Comment: @student080705639 array string or arraylist of type string?. You can check the answer by Nirmal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it like this.

```
listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), array_list[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   /*some code to save data in MainActivity*/
      Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Order.class);
             in.putExtra("ListValue", array_list[position]);    
             startActivity(in);
      }});
```

In your **Order.class**

```
   //to get the value from the MainActivity.this.
    String value= getIntent().getExtras().getString("ListValue");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your code but when I run it, it got an error, the application has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: `the application has stopped unexpectedly`

Comment: Can you post your array_list?

Comment: I'm sorry I know why it get an error, I forget to change my listview name in order.java, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android) to pass the data between Activities.

Second Solution:

You can use `public static Arraylist<String> MyArraylist` in your MainActivity & you can access it in another Activity as `MainActivity.MyArraylist`.