# Android Getting Data From Another Class

Tags: android

I am getting started to Android. I want to get data from another class. I writed some codes but they didn't work. Please help me.

First Activity :

```
Button b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.search);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent a=new Intent(CActivity.this,Db.class);
        a.putExtra("data",bcode);
         startActivity(a);
        }});
```

Second Activity:

```
Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    {
    dContents=extra.getString("data");
    }
```

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android. Please Search before ask.

Comment: what is the datatype of "bcode" ?

Comment: @geet I've read question and answers about this topic but they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @DynamicMind Datatype of bcode is String.

Comment: i guess bcode must be null. what you put is what you get.

Answer (score 0):

In Second Activity,remove all the codes to get the data from the intent and try this

```
dContents = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

I assume data is string.

Comment: @Adaichi I think you passing null value thats why you didn't receive anything. First check what you passing in FirstActivity

Comment: I've checked for this. But there is no change.

Comment: What do you mean no change? Whats the value you passing in First Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dContents=getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

instead of

```
Bundle extra=getIntent().getExtras();
    {
    dContents=extra.getString("data");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think both the code are same. getStringExtra("data") does the same thing as extra.getString("data")

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in you second class file.

```
Intent i = getIntent();

String str = i.getExtra("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Is worked to me**

**First Activity (Set data and start Activity)**

```
           String shocode="0003";
           String shopname="CCT";
           Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),Frame_unproductuv.class);       
                    i.putExtra("shopcode", shocode);
                    i.putExtra("shopname", shopname);
                    startActivity(i);
```

**Second Activity (Get Data)**

```
              Intent intent = getIntent();
              Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
              route_name = b.getString("shopname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// store data to be pass to next activity
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("key", yourString);
startActivity(mIntent);


// extract data from previous activity
if (getIntent() != null) {
String mString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    // do what you going to do with string.
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getIntent() = null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I believe that if you using Bundle to retrieve the string you got to use getStringExtra() and if you using Intent to retrieve the data you use getString().

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the data as a string in your first class then simply retrieve it from your second

```
String shopname = "enteredshopname";
```

then from your second class

```
String getShopName = MainActiviy.shopname;
```

you can then do whatever setText etc that you need to