# Passing values to Activities with putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a value on my ListView to my second activity using `Intents`. I am not sure how to pass the text value to the second activity my `Intent` leads to. Right now my `Intent` is able to connect to the second activity on tap but it doesn't pass the string of the tapped value.

I feel that I need to pass something into my `launchEditItem()` but I am not sure what. These are the two functions I am dealing with right now.

```
private void launchEditItem() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("itemOnList", );     // list item into edit text
    startActivity(i);
}

private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
            launchEditItem();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure what value to place into the `i.putExtra()`, but I think I need to pass an argument into the `launchEditItem()`.

This is what is currently in my second Activity:

```
public class EditItemActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_item);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String ItemToEdit = i.getStringExtra("itemOnList");
        // place into EditText using ItemToEdit
    }
```

I'm also not sure how to place this String value (`ItemToEdit`) into an EditText box. I'm new to android dev so I'm learning as much as I can thank you!

*** EDIT ***

I guess I'm a bit too vague in my question. Here is the entire code of the small app I am working on

```
public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<String> todoItems;        
    private ArrayAdapter<String> todoAdapter;       // declare array adapter which will translate the piece of data to teh view
    private ListView lvItems;                   // attach to list view
    private EditText etNewItem;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
        etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
        //populateArrayItems();                 // call function
        readItems();        // read items from file
        todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
        //todoAdapter.add("item 4");
        setupListViewListener();
        setupEditItemListener();

    }

    private void launchEditItem() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("itemOnList", );     // list item into edit text
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
        lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                launchEditItem();
            }

        });
    }

    private void setupListViewListener() {
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                todoItems.remove(pos);
                todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // has adapter look back at the array list and refresh it's data and repopulate the view
                writeItems();   
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onAddedItem(View v) {
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        todoAdapter.add(itemText);  // add to adapter
        etNewItem.setText("");      //clear edit text
        writeItems();       //each time to add item, you want to write to file to memorize
    }

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));   //populate with read
        }catch (IOException e) {    // if files doesn't exist  
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, todoItems);  // pass todoItems to todoFile
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try google first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: What value do you want to pass to your 2nd activity ? Is it `item.getText()` ?

Comment: Sorry, the item I want to pass to teh 2nd activity is the item I would tap on my ListView

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to pass/select a particular item in a ListView to pass.

Answer (score 5):

```
    String[] link_list;
   int currenttrack=0;

        link_list=new String[]{
            "W-TE_Ys4iwM",//1
            "oozgmH3ZP14",//2
            "o_v9MY_FMcw",//3
            "36mCEZzzQ3o",//4
```

}

First activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            currenttrack=arg2;


            Intent videoIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,VideoView.class);
            videoIntent.putExtra("filename", link_list[currenttrack]);
            startActivity(videoIntent);
        }
    });
```

In your Second Activity

```
    // getting intent data

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    filename = extras.getString("filename");
    Log.e("File Name", filename);
```

and your done :)

Answer (score 2):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i understood where is the value. Well if the value is in EditText do something like:

```
private void launchEditItem(String text) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("itemOnList", text);     // list item into edit text
    startActivity(i);
}

private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
            EditText editView = (EditText) item.findById(R.id.ItemToEdit);
            String text = editView != null ? editView.getText().toString() : "";
            launchEditItem(text);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - I have some doubt with:

```
i.putExtra("itemOnList", );
```

You'd better pass a value:

```
i.putExtra("itemOnList", "something");
```

2 - To valorize a control, you must obtain a reference to it first. Something like:

```
EditText edt =
    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_edit_item_my_EditText); // or whatever id you assigned to it  (it MUST HAVE AN ID)
```

Do it AFTER setContentView().

Then you can set it's text like:

```
edt.setText(ItemToEdit); // Now it should contain "something"
```

Just as simple as that

**[EDIT]**

If you aren't sure what to pass so is to pass in the "tapped" value in the ListView into the `putExtra`, modify your listview click handler code:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener
(
    new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VideoView.class);
            videoIntent.putExtra("filename", (((TextView) v).getText().toString());
            startActivity(videoIntent);
        }
    }
);
```

It should work immediately.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to pass so I left it blank. What I am trying to do is to pass in the "tapped" value in the ListView into the `putExtra`

Answer (score 0):

01: Current Activity

```
String pass_value ="value";

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("var_name",pass_value);
startActivity(intent);
```

02: New Activity

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("var_name");
```