# How to pass integer to a new activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to android. I am taking a string and a numerical value as input from the MainActivity. 
On pressing the button, the following method is called which invokes the second activity.
Am I passing the values correctly?
If yes, how do I receive both these values for use in the second activity and then print them ?

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ma);
    String message = "Hi ! " + editText1.getText().toString();
    int i = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("lol",message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

P.S. I know Im not passing the integer at all. I dont know how to do that. Please help!

Comment: You can access the intent in the other activity using `getIntent()`

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: I need to receive an Integer in the second activity. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the new `Activity` you should call `getIntent()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()

Once you have the `Intent` you have to call `getIntExtra(String, int)`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int).

In your case, from the new Activity something like:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int lol = intent.getIntExtra("lol", 0);
```

Or shorter:

```
int lol = getIntent().getIntExtra("lol", 0);
```

That '0' is the default value for the int if the extra "lol" does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Solvedit right away. But I still didnt understand the use of '0'. Why is it required when we already have the extra "lol" defined .

Comment: If for some reason that extra didn't exist, then lol=0. That way it has a default value, and it's not just non existent. It is useless if you are sure to always have the extra "lol", but only if you are sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this one for integer values
In second activity....

```
    int i = getIntent().getIntExtra(SendingStringName, 0);
    (or)
    String progress = getIntent().getStringExtra(SendingStringName);
    (or)
    ArrayList< String> progress = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra(name);
```

Comment: Why do you need to give examples for `String` or `ArrayList` extras for this. Just the `getIntExtra` example should suffice.

Comment: Isn't getIntent() supposed to be used just once and then we extract all data? Can you explain using it this way?

Comment: You can use these types data extraction I just post the these ways you can send the data And i posted the some example methods to extract other data it's extra information dude you may use this in future so only i put this...You just take the first line for your solution

Answer (score 0):

To send the data:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ma);
String message = "Hi ! " + editText1.getText().toString();
int i = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

Bundle param = new Bundle();
param.putString("greeting",message);
param.putInteger("NumberInteger",i);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(param);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive them: 
In Class DisplayMessageActivity.java do:

```
Intent it = getIntent();
Bundle param = it.getExtras();
String capturedMessage= param.getString("greeting");
Integer captured_I = param.getInteger("NumberInteger");
```