# Use variables between two activities with different processes

Tags: java, android, process

I created my Base activity in separated process by adding to it's `<activity>` `fragment` in `manifest`:

```
android:process=":login_exception_process"
```

In Base activity I initiate my connection objects, and start next Activitty. But from another Activity when I try to get this instances of connection objects they are **`NULL`**.

Objects initiated by Base activity are saved in separated classes in `static` variables. How can I access this variable?

Comment: You can do one more thing. Create one more class which extends application. Declare all your connection variables over there and it will be available to all the activities of app.

Comment: @ZohraKhan - no, that is not really true.  There will be variable available in each process, but they will be *different* ones (different or null instances), and so useless for this purpose.

Comment: You must use some means of interprocess communication - Intent extras as two answers are suggesting below, Binder IPC (commonly seen with AIDL style service binding), unix domain sockets, named pipes, even (at an extreme of setup) shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Passing values to another Activity

You have to start your next activity sending an extra in an Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putextra("keyName","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

And your next Activity, you can retrieve this value by doing this:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("keyName");
```

[Here is the documentation for that.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

---

#### Getting a result from an Activity

Starting another activity doesn't have to be one-way. You can also start another activity and receive a result back. For example, if you want to start the `NextActivity` and return a value back from `NextActivity` to `BaseActivity`, you can use `startActivityForResult()`.

[Here is the documentation for that.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

---

#### Update

Sending objects via intent can be done with two options:

*Pseudo-codes*

**Serializable**

```
intent.putExtra("MyClass", your_object);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

**Parcelable**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);  
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();  
mBundle.putParcelable(PAR_KEY, your_object);  
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Despite **Serializable** seems to be the easiest option, follow this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html) it will teach you both ways.

---

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I need to send big objects, and support methods from previous process  - this will work?

Comment: @igor.stebliy what kind of objects you want to send? And what you mean when you say "support methods from previous process"?

Comment: I create instance of my internate client, methods like reauntefication, i suppouse methods will be accessible.

Comment: @igor.stebliy see the update of my answer. About the methods support, you want to access the methods from the previous **Activity** in your current **Activity**?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Extras`

- [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)

Basically, when creating your intent you have to put extras:

```
intent.putExtra("name", "My name is John");
```

then when you want to get it back when you start the next activity:

```
this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

You can do this with any type if you convert the Object to a byte array.