# Result null in "getStringExtra"

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, getstring

I am working on this code, and get an error, the variable "textoviejo" is returned as **null**, I would like to know what is wrong here. Thank you

**Activity 1**

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input); 
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Activity2.class), REQUEST_CODE_SEND);
Intent i = new Intent(this, EmoticonActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("textoviejo", input.getText().toString());
```

**Activity 2**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();


    String mensaje = intent.getStringExtra("textoviejo");
    String emoticon = mensaje + ":)";
    intent.putExtra(Extra.EMOTICON, emoticon);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

Result in **EditText = null**

Comment: your extraction is wrong. check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: are you a beginner in android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is  EmoticonActivity.class is your activity2 ? if yes then

you are doing it wrong, do it like this

Activity 1

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input); 
Intent i = new Intent(this, EmoticonActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("textoviejo", input.getText().toString()); 
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_SEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

try

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt used

```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
```

and than call

```
  String mensaje = intent.getStringExtra("textoviejo");
```

Comment: it's same answer that i have posted...please remove or give a different one