# Open new class/activity on button click in android

Tags: android

How to open another activity on button click? So now my app has one `main` window ( when you run the app ). Then there is a menu whit some buttons and when I click on some button is open another activity for this button. 
So I have one form which user must enter his details but now I want to click on button `continue` and open another activity where he must enter some more info. Now when this button is clicked the info goes into database.
I know how to add more activities on normal page like `main` where I have only buttons but on this one I don't really know. Here is the code

```
public class Reservation extends Activity {

String Name;
String Email;
String Phone;
String Comment;
String DateTime;
String numberOfPeople;

private EditText editText1, editText3, editText2, editText4, txtDate, numberOfPeoples; //, txtTime;
private Button btnMenues, btnCalendar, btnTimePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personName);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personPhone);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personEmail);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personComment);
    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    numberOfPeoples = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfPeoples);

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    //btnTimePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTimePicker);
    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueWithReservation);


    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Reservation.this, ReservationSecond.class);
            intent.putExtra(Name, Name.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Email, Email.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Phone, Phone.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Comment, Comment.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(DateTime, DateTime.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(numberOfPeople, numberOfPeople.getBytes().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 
}
```

So what I can put in `setOnClickListener` to go on next activity?

Update:
If I change this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Name = editText1.getText().toString();
            Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
            Email = editText2.getText().toString();
            Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
            DateTime = txtDate.getText().toString();
            numberOfPeople = numberOfPeoples.getText().toString();
            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
        }
```

to this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contacts.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

How to keep the information that user is added so far for next activity and save in DB after he finish with second activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Intent` and then call `startActivity()` with that `Intent`:

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener() {
    public void onClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) give a pretty good explanation

**EDIT**

To address the question you gave in the comment, the easiest way to pass information between `Activities` is to use extras like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(NAME, VALUE);
startActivity(intent);
```

There are [multiple versions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) of `putExtra` to accomodate passing different types of values

Another way to store information would be to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). [Here is a simple example](http://codetheandroid.blogspot.com/2012/06/passing-data-in-android-using.html)

You could also create a `public` class called, for example, `Storage` and have your data be represented as `static` member(s) of this class (accessed like `Storage.MY_DATA`) so it can be accessed from any point in your application.

Comment: I use this in my `MainActivity` but if I use this here how to pass store the info that I have already? I mean if I go on another activity I will loose it?

Comment: So If I understand you corectly I must define `Name = editText1.getText().toString();.. and others` somewhere outside of `public void onClick()` and in `onClick` event to use `intent.putExtra(NAME, VALUE);` where on multiple lines I add Name and Values.

Comment: @Goro Yessir. That would be one of the ways.

Comment: Ok, last question. Can you tell me where in the current code I can define them?

Comment: Well, the way you have it right now is fine. You declared them globally, then inside `onClick` you get their values. Now you can just put them as extras after that and then call the second activity. Where you define them is specific to your coding style and how your application needs to access those resources, the only thing you **have to do** is obtain the value **before** passing them as extras to make sure they exist and you don't end up passing `null` values for example.

Comment: Here is how you get the data from the secondActivity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: Defined them like this? I've edited my question source code. And now on `onClick` I just pass their values.

Comment: @Goro, well you are not putting any extra information into the intent? What you need to do is combine the way your `onClick` is currently setup (where you obtain data like `Name` etc.) with the way you suggested to change the setup of your `onClick` (where you create an `Intent` and start second activity) and also add the `putExtra` for all your data to the intent

Comment: Sorry, i've edited again. Is that what we talking about?

Comment: And `getBytes()` or something eles/

Comment: `"Unfortunate the app has stopped` .. I've put on second activity in `onCreate()` -> `Intent intent = getIntent();
     getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
     getIntent().getStringExtra("Email");..`

Comment: Well I will accept your answer since is helped me to start second activity. But I have a problem with the second one but I'll try to fix it and if I can't I will post new thread. Thank's