# Activity doesn't keep the passed information android

Tags: android

I have 2 activities. First activity has and form which user can insert some information. Then there is a button which lead to second activity where user insert some more information and buton Save which save in MySQL database. 
I use `intent.putExtra` but doesn't save anything in DB. Since I'm new to android I'm not sure that this is correct. I've used as reference this post [How to get extra data from intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android?lq=1) 
This is first activity

```
public class Reservation extends Activity {
    static String Name;
static String Email;
static String Phone;
static String Comment;
static String DateTime;
static String numberOfPeople;

private EditText editText1, editText3, editText2, editText4, txtDate, editText5; 
private Button btnMenues, btnCalendar, btnTimePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personName);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personPhone);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personEmail);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.personComment);
    txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);
    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continueWithReservation);


    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Name = editText1.getText().toString();
            //Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
            //Email = editText2.getText().toString();
            //Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
            //DateTime = txtDate.getText().toString();
            //DateTime = txtTime.getText().toString();
            //numberOfPeople = numberOfPeoples.getText().toString();
            //new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Reservation.this, ReservationSecond.class);
            String Name = editText1.getText().toString();
            String Email = editText2.getText().toString();
            String Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
            String Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
            String DateTime = txtDate.getText().toString();
            String numberOfPeople = editText5.getText().toString();

            intent.putExtra(Name, Name.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Email, Email.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Phone, Phone.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(Comment, Comment.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(DateTime, DateTime.getBytes().toString());
            intent.putExtra(numberOfPeople, numberOfPeople.getBytes().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

and this is second activity which has to receive the data and save in BD

```
public class ReservationSecond extends Activity {

String getName;
String getEmail;
String getPhone;
String getComment;
String getDateTime;
String getnumberOfPeople;

private Button btnMenues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reservation_second);

    btnMenues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);

    btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                getName = extras.getString("Name");
                getEmail = extras.getString("Email");
                getPhone = extras.getString("Phone");
                getComment = extras.getString("Comment");
                getDateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
                getnumberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
        }

            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);

            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }); 
}

class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String getNameToData, String getEmailData, String getPhoneData,
            String getCommentData, String getDateTimeData, String getnumberOfPeopleData) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://link/saveReservation.php");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", getNameToData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", getEmailData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", getPhoneData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", getCommentData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", getDateTimeData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfPeople", getnumberOfPeopleData));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        postData(getName, getEmail, getPhone, getComment, getDateTime, getnumberOfPeople );
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Update. In second activity like this?

```
if (extras != null) {
                extras.getString("Name");
                extras.getString("Email");
                extras.getString("Phone");
                extras.getString("Comment");
                extras.getString("DateTime");
                extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
            }
```

instead of

```
                if (extras != null) {
                String Name = extras.getString("Name");
                String Email = extras.getString("Email");
                String Phone = extras.getString("Phone");
                String Comment = extras.getString("Comment");
                String DateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
                String numberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
            }
```

This is the `getReservation.php`

```
$icon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if(!$icon)
{
   die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_erroe());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $icon)or die("database selection error");
echo json_encode($data);

$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Comment=$_POST['Comment'];
$DateTime=$_POST['DateTime'];
$numberOfPeople=$_POST['numberOfPeople'];

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (Name, Phone, Email, Comment, DateTime, numberOfPeople)
VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Comment', NOW(), '$numberOfPeople')",$icon);
```

mysql_close($icon);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the value entered by user as the key in extras. So there won't be any value if you try to get that by "Name" key.

Use

```
    intent.putExtra("Name", Name.getBytes().toString());
```

instead of

```
    intent.putExtra(Name, Name.getBytes().toString());
```

Also in second activity use global variables you declared instead of creating local ones. As you are passing global variables and initializing the local ones.

Use

```
    if (extras != null) {
            Name = extras.getString("Name");
            Email = extras.getString("Email");
            Phone = extras.getString("Phone");
            Comment = extras.getString("Comment");
            DateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
            numberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
    }
```

Comment: I think it does not matter. And might be that are added to convert string to other encoding. It answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank's but still doesn't save anything in DB when I press finish button in second activity.

Comment: You are using local variables in second activity's onclick method, you should use the variables declared in class instead of redeclaring it and it should work.

Comment: Tried your edit also this what I write in my edit. Nothing in DB. I will post the `.php` script also

Comment: No you haven't added the assignment in your edit. Assign the global variables you have declared. See the difference. I have used Name = extras.getString("Name"); and you have used only extras.getString("Name");

Comment: Sorry I've added it on my side but forgot to edit it here. Now I edited it.

Comment: I saw something strange. On second activity I must click 2 times on `Finish` button. Then save in DB but empty rows i.e. doesn't take the info from first activity or is loosed after first click on `Finish`

Comment: I think the problem here is you are using same names for local and global variables, same problem with asynctask when you call the postData method. Name global variables different, assign them from extras, use it when calling the postData. And in declaration of postData use different names than global variables. Clean up your code, it is messed up. Also use camel case for variable names. Also log the value of variables and try to debug. Check whether the values are available at each point.

Comment: I've edited my second activity in question. Change them like this?

Comment: use different names in private void postData(String getName, String getEmail, String getPhone, String getComment, String getDateTime, String getnumberOfPeople) and use the new names while adding BasicNameValuePairs

Comment: Done this (updated in question) and still nothing goes to DB.

Comment: How can I check them?

Comment: can we continue here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64219/discussion-between-ravivadera-and-goro

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) for how putExtra() works and what you have to give it as input
[image]

In order to get your extra's like this

```
extras.getString("Name");
```

you have to put them like this

```
intent.putExtra("Name", Name.getBytes().toString());
```

note the extra quotation marks around Name

Also, because you are passing strings, you can just do

```
intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
```

the -> bytes -> String conversion is redundant

Comment: Thank's. I've tried like this but still doesn't save anything in DB when I press `finish` button in second activity.

Comment: What is the output? any errors? There are a lot of possible causes for the DB write to not work, we can not always guess it by looking at the code

Comment: Nothing. Not errors, not warnings.It just reload the activity as must do. Where I can check for the output?

Comment: On your webserver maybe? We have no way to know what happens there

Comment: Sorry but no errors also on host. Before to put second activity it saves normally in database. But after I made second activity doesn't want.

Answer (score 1):

You are handing over the value as **both key and value**. That cannot work since a changing value would also change the key and prevent you from getting your information in the second `Activity`.

Try this:

```
intent.putExtra("Name", Name.getBytes().toString());
intent.putExtra("Email", Email.getBytes().toString());
intent.putExtra("Phone", Phone.getBytes().toString());
intent.putExtra("Comment", Comment.getBytes().toString());
intent.putExtra("DateTime", DateTime.getBytes().toString());
intent.putExtra("numberOfPeople", numberOfPeople.getBytes().toString());
```