# How to update Fragment and Background in another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

long story short.

I have the mainActivity with two Fragments. So instead of the mainActivity there are the two Fragments. 
In the first Fragment there is a Switch.

Is it possible to update the background from the mainActivity when the switch is checked or unchecked? The Background is set in the content_main.xml, because then you have no transition when changing the fragments.

So is it at all possible?

I thought this would work:

```
if(switch.isChecked()) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("background1", R.drawable.background2);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

And in the MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int bg = sharedPref.getInt("background1", R.drawable.background1);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(bg);
```

Or is it just not possible because the fragment isn't loading itself new? 
If so. How is it possible?

Thanks in advance guys

source:

[Changing background of an activity from another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338691/changing-background-of-an-activity-from-another-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve that. I think the easiest way to do so is through a listener/callback.

First of all, create your listener class:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void onSwitchStateChanged(boolean isChecked);
}
```

After that, make your Activity implement that interface, and implement your background changing logic inside the `onSwitchStateChanged` method.

Now, inside your Fragment's `onAttach()` method, do the following (this example is in Kotlin):

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is MyCallback) {
        myListener = context as MyCallback
    }
    else {
        throw RuntimeException("Must implement MyCallback!")
    }
}
```

Where `myListener` is a variable inside your fragment.

Now add a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on your switch, like it's described on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278528/4070469), and use the callback inside it. For example (in Java):

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        myListener.onSwitchStateChanged(isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great thank you! To switch it back I've added in the `onCheckedChanged` method `if(isChecked == true) {
            background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background1);
        } else {
            background.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background2);
        }`. So it's perfectly working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use callback interface to communicate between fragment and your activity

Please see the below code snippet :

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

   OnCallbackReceived mCallback;

// Implement this interface in your Activity.

public interface OnCallbackReceived {
    public void Update(boolean state);
}
```

In your fragment :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnCallbackReceived) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {

    }
}

// You can Call the event from fragment as mentioned below
// mCallback is the activity context. 
mCallback.Update(switch.isChecked());
```

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements YourFragment.OnCallbackReceived {

// Implemented method.
public override void Update(boolean state) {
    // Update bg here
}
```

Original:

[How to send data from fragment to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429603/how-to-send-data-from-fragment-to-activity)

Answer (score 2):

use Otto event bus,It's easy and simple

Click this [link](http://square.github.io/otto/)

add this to your dependencies

```
implementation compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
```

Activity or Fragment onCreate add this one

```
Bus bus = new Bus();
```

You can post event like this from your activity or fragment

```
bus.post(new AnswerAvailableEvent(42));
```

if you want to get events even when your fragment is in the foreground or background, Subscribe to the events like below

```
@Subscribe public void answerAvailable(AnswerAvailableEvent event) {
// TODO: React to the event somehow!
}
```

Don't forget to register and unregister in onStart and onStop

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
 super.onStart();
 bus.register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
 super.onStop();
 bus.unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: Although using an EventBus could solve his problem, your answer is link only, try to improve it. For more information, see ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help Center.