# java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start actvity component info java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

I need to pass the variable from onCreate method to OnClickListener...

```
// onCreate method
String num2 = bundle.getString("phno"); 

// onClickListener method
s.sendTextMessage(no,null,msg,null,null);
```

here in "no" place i need to use the String which i get in the Oncreatemethod from another activity...i know that navigating the activities using bundle and i used that method here... i need help in **"num2"** which i get in the **oncreate** method to **onclick listener** in **"no"** place....

i tried simply with String `no=num2;` but it doesnt work

Comment: Usual way is to use an intent to pass data between activities, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android

Comment: Indeed, arguments from another activity come as part of an Intent - the bundle would not have that, but rather potentially the saved state of your instance.

Answer (score 1):

declare String "no" globally..

Comment: "no", this is not meaningfully a solution to the problem.