# findViewById from different layout/xml file Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, findviewbyid

I'm trying to create a settings page for my app which has the radioGroup for 3 options to help users change the colour of the text in differrent layout/xml file. But in mysettings page I cant call the view from different layout, any idea?

Below are my codes:

```
Settings.Java

    package com.example.sunny.mynote;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.EditText;



    /**
     * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
     */
    public class Settings extends Activity {

        private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
        private RadioButton rdbRed, rdbBlue, rdbOrange;
        private Button btnSave;
        private EditText editText;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);

            RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

            RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    if(checkedId == R.id.rdbRed)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Red",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(checkedId == R.id.rdbBlue)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Blue",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Orange",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            rdbRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbRed);
            rdbBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbBlue);
            rdbOrange = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbOrange);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
                        //textView.setText("You chose 'Sound' option");
                    } else if(selectedId == rdbBlue.getId()) {
                        //textView.setText("You chose 'Vibration' option");
                    } else {
                        //textView.setText("You chose 'Silent' option");
                    }
                    finish();
                }

            });




        }
  @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

        }
    }
```

and I want to FindViewbyID from this layout, an EditText from this view to be exactly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/noteText"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You want to keep the color code in common and in on resume create the activity again.

Comment: I want to editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); the editText is actually from a different layout how can I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this edit text in this activity??

Comment: I want to change the color of the text in editText

Comment: In my if statement I want to do sth like this  if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
textView.setTextColor(MyColor); But the problem is I cant get the textView from anorther layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an intent with extras like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,Class.class);
i.putExtra("ColorChoice",color);
```

And then extract this data from your main class with:

```
intent.getStringExtra("ColorChoice");
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. In my if statement I want to do sth like this  if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
textView.setTextColor(MyColor); But the problem is I cant get the textView from anorther layout.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in your `Settings.java` activity if your `editText` is not in this activity.

You can either use `intent` with `putExtra` and `getExtra` like @user3624383 mentioned. (more on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html))

Or a better way would be to use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save your settings even if the user exits your app and return to it later

Comment: so now if i do this Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);    what should i put in my if statement so when the rdbRed is checked the text of the EditText in NoteEditorActivity will change its color to Red

Comment: with `intent.putExtra`, yes it can work but I wouldn't recommend them. `SharedPreferences` are meant for these things

Comment: Can you please show me how to use intent to do this?

Comment: There are many examples online. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android) is one...

Comment: So intent basiclly is to get data from another activity. But what if I dont want to get data from another activity, I want to change data from another activity.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences`. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example) for an example