# Getting bundle on Main activity when passing bundles by intent in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-bundle

So the problem I am having is that my app keeps crashing on launch, I have two activities. Activity A and Activity B. My app launches on Activity A but I have created a bundle in Activity B and I am sending it to Activity A. So when it launches the bundle is empty or null so it crashes, how do i fix this? thanks.

This is in Activity A (Launching Activity) in on create

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Title = extras.getString("Title");
    Description = extras.getString("Description");
    Price = extras.getString("Price");
    Availability = extras.getString("Availability");
```

Then we have me creating the bundle in Activity B

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("Title", PostTitle);
                extras.putString("Description", PostDescription);
                extras.putString("Price", PostPrice);
                extras.putString("Availability", PostAvail);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest the following:

A. Use Bundle from Intent:

```
Intent pIntent = new Intent(this, JustaClass.class);
Bundle extras = pIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

B. Create a new Bundle:

```
Intent pIntent = new Intent(this, JustaClass.class);
Bundle pBundle = new Bundle();
pBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(pBundle);
```

C. Use putExtra() method of the Intent:

```
Intent pIntent = new Intent(this, JustaClass.class);
pIntent.putExtra(key, value);
```

Finally in the launched Activity, you can read them hrough:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key)
```

I just used Strings as an example for passing, I refer to [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: In my case if I send intent to activity in another app, only B works for me