# startActivity also has an optional parameter for Bundle, What is the correct way to use this method and retrieve the bundle in destination activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, android-fragmentactivity

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP5vl.png***emphasized text***

I know the other way to pass the Bundle to the destination activity is by creating an Intent and then setting the Bundle in the extras of the intent and then in the destination activity we can get the intent and then ask for the extras and then access the bundle

I am not sure how use the below method

```
startActivity(Intent intent, @RecentlyNullable Bundle options)
```

Comment: That version of `startActivity()` does not use the `Bundle` to pass data to the started activity. That `Bundle` is used to configure how the activity is started. See [the documentation for that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle)) and see [the documentation for `ActivityOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions) for how to create that `Bundle`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting bundle on Main activity when passing bundles by intent in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599972/getting-bundle-on-main-activity-when-passing-bundles-by-intent-in-android)