# Clear variable when Android back button is clicked

Tags: android, string, textview, back-button

I have an app where I would like to be able to click on a button, A, and show a certain set of information. Then click the back button and click on button B and show a different set of information. I have coded a test TextView into the Drinks.java file in order to begin the process by confirming what is being passed along. Currently whatever button I push first is getting stuck in the variable. So for example if I push button A, then push the back arrow and push button B, button A is still showing up in the textView. I tried making the Strings empty within the on click listener, to "clear them out" as it were, but that isn't working. Is there a way to wipe out what is in the variable and reassign something else? Or does my problem lie elsewhere?

Bar.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bar extends Activity{
    String setBarTest = MainActivity.setBar;
    String barNameHolder, picHolder, barContactHolder, barPhoneHolder; 
    int imageInt, textInt1,textInt2, textInt3;
    TextView setBarName, setBarContact,setBarPhone;
    ImageView barPic;
    Button viewAll, beer, wine, mixedDrinks, other, getTaxi;
    static String setDrinkType = "";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar);

        Button viewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnviewAll);
        Button beer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBeer);
        Button wine = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWine);
        Button mixedDrinks = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMixedDrinks);
        Button other = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOther);
        Button getTaxi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTaxi);

        barPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barPic);
        String picHolder = "drawable/"+setBarTest;      
        int imageInt = getResources().getIdentifier(picHolder, null, getPackageName());
        barPic.setImageResource(imageInt);

        setBarName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barName);
        String barNameHolder = "@string/"+setBarTest;
        int textInt1 = getResources().getIdentifier(barNameHolder, null, getPackageName());
        setBarName.setText(textInt1);

        setBarContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barContact);
        String barContactHolder = "@string/"+setBarTest+"Contact";
        int textInt2 = getResources().getIdentifier(barContactHolder, null, getPackageName());
        setBarContact.setText(textInt2);

        setBarPhone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.barPhone);
        String barPhoneHolder = "@string/"+setBarTest+"Phone";
        int textInt3 = getResources().getIdentifier(barPhoneHolder, null, getPackageName());
        setBarPhone.setText(textInt3);

        viewAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Drinks.class));
                startActivity(i);           
            }

        });
        beer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDrinkType = "";
                setDrinkType = "Beer";
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Drinks.class));
                startActivity(i); 

            }

        });
        wine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDrinkType = "";
                setDrinkType = "Wine";
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Drinks.class));
                startActivity(i);   

            }

        });
        mixedDrinks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDrinkType = "";
                setDrinkType = "Mixed Drink";
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Drinks.class));
                startActivity(i); 

            }

        });

        other.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDrinkType = "";
                setDrinkType = "Other";
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Drinks.class));
                startActivity(i); 

            }

        });
        getTaxi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = (new Intent(Bar.this, Taxi.class));
                startActivity(i);           
            }

        });


    }
}
```

Drinks.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Drinks extends Activity{
    TextView drinkHolder;
    public static String drinkType = Bar.setDrinkType;
    String drinkTestHolder="";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drinks);
        drinkTestHolder = drinkType;
        drinkHolder = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.drinkTest);
        //String barNameHolder = "@string/"+drinkType;
        //int textInt1 = getResources().getIdentifier(barNameHolder, null, getPackageName());
        drinkHolder.setText(drinkTestHolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you simply say what you want to do ? because your description is little bit messy ...

Comment: I want the "setDrinkType " variable to change depending on which button is pushed. Currently it is stuck so that is the user pushes a button, then clicks the back button and pushes a different  button, the first string is still there.

Comment: it is because your setDrinkType is a static variable

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use instead for instance the intent sent to the launching Activity:

[How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)