# Android: parameters from tabActivity to an activity are null

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, oncreate

I am using the following code to pass parameters from a tabActivity to an AppCompatActivity called Eventi:

TabActivity:

```
Intent eventi = new Intent(this,Eventi.class);
eventi.putExtra("title,",title);
eventi.putExtra("testo",desc);
```

and this is the code I use to recall the parameters **which I can retrieve from the onStart() method**.

Eventi AppCompatActivity:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String not = extras.getString("title");
 String messaggio = extras.getString("message");
```

Anyway `extras` is always null. why?

Comment: Try in onCreate  rather than onStart() Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null)

Answer (score 0):

what you should be using when retrieving extras from bundle is...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent();
String not = extras.getStringExtra("title");
String messaggio = extras.getStringExtra("message");
```

also check if the variable you are passing has a value.

Comment: from what i've seen, getArguments() is used by fragments while getIntent() is for getting the extras of an intent. the line of code i've posted works very well. try it

Comment: this is where i got it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure both are activities.
Then in tabActivity :
Here make sure title and desc are string type, also debug to check they are not null or empty when u startActivity.

```
Intent eventi = new Intent(this,Eventi.class);
eventi.putExtra("title,",title);
eventi.putExtra("testo",desc);
```

Next in Eventi AppCompatActivity in the Oncreate() method :

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String not = extras.getStringExtra("title");
 String messaggio = extras.getStringExtra(***"testo"***);
```