# Send string variable between from first activity to fourth activity

Tags: android

How to send string variable from the first activity to the fourth activity ?

I got 2 string variables on my first activity, I want to pass them to the fourth activity. How would I fetch the data if I use this syntax ?

```
    Public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static String first_string ;
        public static String last_string ;
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this
1) Use `Intent` method.

In the first activity
intent.putExtra("firststring",firststring);

In the fourth activity

```
String first = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firststring");
```

So similiar process in 2nd 3rd activity.

2) Use sharedpreference method

In the first activity

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit(); editor.putString("firststring", firststring);
```

In the fourth activity

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";


SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String firststing = sharedpreferences.getString("firststring", "firststring");
```

Answer (score 0):

As of right now you could just access them from **FourthActivity** with:

```
String first_string_new = FirstActivity.first_string;
```

---

***But***, I would recommend you to avoid static values and pass them as extras with used [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

From **FirstActivity**:

```
intent.putExtra("FIRST_STRING", first_string);
intent.putExtra("SECOND_STRING", last_string);
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive the strings in the **FourthActivity**:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String first_string_new = extras.getString("FIRST_STRING");
String second_string_new = extras.getString("SECOND_STRING");
```

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android) to see another example using extras in the Intent.

Comment: I want to know, will the startactivity(intent) line directly start activity4 ?

Comment: Yes, if you create the Intent as:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);`

Comment: But I don't want to, so how will I process to get to activities 2&3 before activity4 ?

Comment: I would still try to avoid static variables or Singletons, and pass the strings via extras from Activity1 to Activity2, from Activity2 to Activity 3 and finally to Activity4, your testing frameworks will be easier to implement if you avoid the approaches mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it was a shortcut. Thanks to help