# How to pass image URL using intent and bundles in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json

I am new to Android apps. I'm doing JSON parsing for my listview. When I click on my list Image I need to pass that Image to second activity. I'm trying to pass it using intent and bundles. But I have image URL so I don't know how to pass it. I searched everywhere others are passing bitmaps or id.

Comment: you should be adding up a code segment in your question. without that, its difficult to guess what you are trying to achieve

Comment: here is my adapter code :  https://jsfiddle.net/4co6gh7z/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Comment: sry.. Iam not getting.. still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class- FirstActivity

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imageUrl",<url for image>);
Intent i= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.this);
i.putExtras(bundle);
statrActivity(i)
```

Class- SecondActivity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String image_url =bundle.getString("imageUrl");
```

Answer (score 0):

your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("IMAGE_URL",your_image_url);
startActivity(intent);
```

in Second activity where you want data

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String image_url =bundle.getString("IMAGE_URL");
```

pass image_url from one activity to another activity, and then use picasso lib to show image.

Comment: no actually i stored my image url in a view holder.. from there i have to pass.. here is my custom adapter code:   https://jsfiddle.net/4co6gh7z/

Answer (score 0):

In **FirstActivity**, in the **onClickListener**, add this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

intent.putExtras(SecondActivity.KEY_IMAGE_URL, image_url);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in **SecondActivity**

```
public static final String KEY_IMAGE_URL = "image_url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_IMAGE_URL)) {
        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_IMAGE_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im using holder.ivIcon, where im holding image url.. so how i have to use SecondActivity.KEY_IMAGE_URL, image_url

Comment: `image_url` should be replaced by `holder.ivIcon`