# Passing Multiple value in Bundle, value assigned in last String is getting passed to all string

Tags: java, android, android-bundle

I'm trying to pass 9 string from one java class to another class via Bundle. But in the another screen, value assigned to last extra is overwritten to all other string.

Class1

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

public  static String  Buy_Price;
public  static String  Sell_Price;
public  static String  QUANTITY;
public  static String  BROKERAGE;
public  static String  ActualProfitLoss_String;
public  static String  TurnOver_String;
public  static String  STT_String;
public  static String  ServiceTax_String;
public  static String  TotalCharge_String;
public  static String  x;
private static  String Strin ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}

public void calculateProfit(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, displayProfit.class);
    Bundle extras =new Bundle();
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    String buyPriceString = editText3.getText().toString();
    Float BuyPrice =  Float.parseFloat(buyPriceString);
    String quantityString = editText2.getText().toString();
    Float Quantity =  Float.parseFloat(quantityString);
    String sellPriceString = editText4.getText().toString();
    Float SellPrice =  Float.parseFloat(sellPriceString);
    String brokerageString = editText.getText().toString();
    Float Brokerage =  Float.parseFloat(brokerageString);

    double TurnOver=(BuyPrice*Quantity)+(SellPrice*Quantity);
    double Sell1 =SellPrice-(SellPrice*(Brokerage/100));
    double Buy1 = BuyPrice+(BuyPrice*(Brokerage/100));
    double TotalBrokerage = ((Sell1*.03)+(Buy1*0.3));
    double STT = (Quantity*(SellPrice-(SellPrice*(Brokerage/100))))*(.025/100);
    double TrnxChrge = TurnOver*(0.00275/100);
    double ServiceTax = (TotalBrokerage+STT)*(15/100);
    double SEBICharge = (TurnOver*(.0002/100));
    double TotalCharge = ServiceTax+TrnxChrge+SEBICharge+STT;
    double NetProfit = (Sell1-Buy1)*Quantity;
    double ActualProfitLoss = (NetProfit -TotalCharge);


    String ActualProfitLossString=Double.toString(ActualProfitLoss);
    String TurnOverString=Double.toString(TurnOver);
    String STTString=Double.toString(STT);
    String ServiceTaxString=Double.toString(ServiceTax);
    String TotalChargeString=Double.toString(TotalCharge);


    extras.putString(ActualProfitLoss_String,ActualProfitLossString);
    extras.putString(TurnOver_String,TurnOverString);
    extras.putString(STT_String,STTString);
    extras.putString(ServiceTax_String,ServiceTaxString);
    extras.putString(TotalCharge_String,TotalChargeString);
    extras.putString(Buy_Price,buyPriceString);
    extras.putString(Sell_Price,sellPriceString);
    extras.putString(BROKERAGE,brokerageString);
    extras.putString(QUANTITY,quantityString);
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class displayProfit extends AppCompatActivity {


private static  String Strin ;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(Strin, "buyPrice :::");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_profit);

    Intent intent =getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra(HomeScreen.x);
    String Buy_Price = extras.getString(HomeScreen.Buy_Price);
    String Sell_Price = extras.getString(HomeScreen.Sell_Price);
    String QUANTITY = extras.getString(HomeScreen.QUANTITY);
    String BROKERAGE = extras.getString(HomeScreen.BROKERAGE);
    String ActualProfitLoss_String = extras.getString(HomeScreen.ActualProfitLoss_String);
    String TurnOver_String = extras.getString(HomeScreen.TurnOver_String);
    String STT_String = extras.getString(HomeScreen.STT_String);
    String ServiceTax_String = extras.getString(HomeScreen.ServiceTax_String);
    String TotalCharge_String = extras.getString(HomeScreen.TotalCharge_String);


    TextView Buy_Price1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Buy_Price1);
    TextView Sell_Price1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sell_Price1);
    TextView QUANTITY1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QUANTITY1);
    TextView BROKERAGE1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BROKERAGE1);
    TextView ActualProfitLoss_String1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ActualProfitLoss_String1);
    TextView TurnOver_String1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TurnOver_String1);
    TextView STT_String1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.STT_String1);
    TextView ServiceTax_String1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ServiceTax_String1);
    TextView TotalCharge_String1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalCharge_String1);


    Buy_Price1.setText(Buy_Price);
    Sell_Price1.setText(Sell_Price);
    QUANTITY1.setText(QUANTITY);
    BROKERAGE1.setText(BROKERAGE);
    ActualProfitLoss_String1.setText(ActualProfitLoss_String);
    TurnOver_String1.setText(TurnOver_String);
    STT_String1.setText(STT_String);
    ServiceTax_String1.setText(ServiceTax_String);
    TotalCharge_String1.setText(TotalCharge_String);

}

}
```

In the end of class2 I placed log and found that Value assigned to QUANTITY is getting populated for all the string.

Please clarify the above. If you more code needed will share the same.

> ### Logs for the same after changing the Class1 as suggested in answer
>
> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>      W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>      W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>      I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 25273(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(264KB) LOS objects, 44% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 14.345ms total 168.562ms
>
> ```
>        [ 02-20 23:21:14.614  3314: 3314 D/         ]
> ```
>
> buyPrice :::
>
> [ 02-20 23:21:14.861  3314: 3314 D/         ]
>      NotNull::::::
>      D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> ```
>        --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: com.test.tax, PID: 3314
>      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.tax/com.test.tax.displayProfit}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>      at com.test.tax.displayProfit.onCreate(displayProfit.java:29)
>      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>      Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8625', transport: 'socket'

Comment: please share the values assigned to `HomeScreen.QUANTITY`, `HomeScreen.BROKERAGE`, `HomeScreen.Sell_Price` etc.

Comment: @AdityaSharat Edited my question. Added whole code.

Comment: In Class 1 (HomeScreen) there must be a `public static String ActualProfitLoss_String`, `public static String QUANTITY` etc. Please add that part of the code. All the nine `public static String` fields in `HomeScreen`

Comment: Added whole Code of class 1 except import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize all the above `public static String`s which you are using to add items into the `Bundle` with **unique** values else they will override each other. eg.

```
public  static String  Buy_Price = "a";
public  static String  Sell_Price = "b";
public  static String  QUANTITY = "c";
public  static String  BROKERAGE = "d";
public  static String  ActualProfitLoss_String = "e";
public  static String  TurnOver_String = "f";
public  static String  STT_String = "g";
public  static String  ServiceTax_String = "h";
public  static String  TotalCharge_String = "i";
public  static String  x =  = "j";
```

Also, they should ideally be `public static final String`. Please consider using a consistent naming convention too (TOTAL_CHARGE, TURN_OVER).

You can imagine the `Bundle` as a Map, if you put values with the same key, the values will be overridden. That is why you got the value of `QUANTITY` in for all the keys because all the keys were null (equal) and `QUANTITY` was the last key you put in the `Bundle`.

EDIT: 
For the `NullPointerException`.

In Class 1 (HomeScreen) inside `calculateProfit(View view)` method you put the `Bundle` in the `Intent` without a key.

```
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

Then in Class 2 (displayProfit) inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` you get the `Bundle` from the `Intent` with a key.

```
intent.getBundleExtra(HomeScreen.x);
```

So put the extras using the same key in HomeScreen like so

```
intent.putExtra(HomeScreen.x, extras);
```

Comment: After changing the code accordingly I'm getting below error.

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.test.tax, PID: 3314
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.tax/com.test.tax.displayProfit}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: try a clean build of your application. could be because of instant run which launches the open Activity. Also, share the entire log, use pastebin or github gists :)

Comment: Added the logs and class 2 code in my question. please check

Comment: error is coming in line 29

ie

    
        String Buy_Price = extras.getString(HomeScreen.Buy_Price);

Comment: yes, that is because at line 28 : `Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra(HomeScreen.x);` extras is null. I have updated the answer. please check it out, you need to make one change in HomeScreen.

Comment: ref to this so question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android

Comment: Yes it worked after removing **Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra(HomeScreen.x);** Thanks