# Android Intent "Expression Expected"

Tags: android, android-intent

I am following the Sams 24hr programming book, but for the life of me cannot seem to fix an issue i am having with Hour 2.

I am trying to create a simple button that launches a second activity and changes the TextArea on the second activity.

This is my code for the second activity. I am getting "Expression Expected" on the Intent in "Intent= getIntent();" and "getStringExtra" is non static method cannot be referenced from static content.

My code looks the same as my book :S

```html
package co.jamesbrown.hour2app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Intent= getIntent();
        String message = Intent.getStringExtra("co.jamesbrown.MESSAGE");
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        messageTextView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: Use some IDE, Like Android studio and all. you will get to know the compile time errors at the time of writing the code. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the answer given , you can also write it in another way

```
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("co.jamesbrown.MESSAGE");
```

Source : [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23658177/5156075)

Comment: Thanks Mate, not sure why they split it in the book. But this makes perfect sense. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Correct it to as below

```
 Intent intent= getIntent();
 String message = intent.getStringExtra("co.jamesbrown.MESSAGE");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Intent= getIntent();` this is not a `Java` expresssion. You need to give a name while declaring the variable in `Java` like this :

```
Intent yourIntent = getIntent();
```

then you can do :

```
String message = yourIntent.getStringExtra("co.jamesbrown.MESSAGE");
```

to get the `String` value passed through the `Intent`.