# How to pass layout ID between 2 activities

Tags: android

I'd like to pass a layout ID (or any id) between 2 Android activities. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android

Comment: just add the id as a int on the Intent and get it as a int in the another activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ID",10000);
startActivity(intent);
```

at `SecondActivity.class`

```
int ID = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID"); // getStringExtra("ID");
```