# Get URI from Bundle

Tags: android

How to get URI from Bundle? I have tried the below code, but data.getExtras(); will give error and data.getData() will give null .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,

                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) {

 final Uri imageUri = data.getExtras();
final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
}
}
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android) answer.

Comment: data.getExtras() gives a Bundle, docs say the uri is in getData(), but you have to set the intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get URI from Bundle?

You don't, usually.

> but data.getExtras(); will give error

That is because `getExtras()` returns a `Bundle`, not a `Uri`.

> and data.getData() will give null

Either the user did not pick anything or there is a bug in the `ACTION_PICK` activity that the user chose for this request.

Also, please note that those extras that you are putting on `ACTION_PICK` are undocumented, unsupported, and will not be honored on many devices. There are plenty of [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

In addition, `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type. `ACTION_PICK` says "pick a piece of content from this collection of content". If you want to limit things by MIME type, use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (and no `Uri` in the `Intent`) or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to say "give me a piece of content that matches this MIME type".

Comment: Add that he has to set the action and is the perfect answer.

Comment: my intention is just to get the uri upon selecting an image from Gallery. I have the code for API > 22. I need the code for lollipop. Can you give some example or reference?

Comment: @MatiasOlocco: I am not sure what you are referring to. The question has `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`. `ACTION_PICK` is an action. However, I do see that the question has `setType()`, which is not used with `ACTION_PICK`, so I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @djac: "my intention is just to get the uri upon selecting an image from Gallery" -- that is not possible in general. `ACTION_PICK` and `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` allow the *user* to choose the activity that responds to that `Intent`, if there is more than one on the device. There is no requirement that the user choose some sort of gallery app. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` brings up a system-supplied UI for choosing the content.

Comment: @CommonsWare perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

If you don't add that your `data.getData()` would be null

Comment: `ACTION_PICK` returns a `Uri` if the user picks a piece of content.