# ANDROID STUDIO: Transferring data from first form to list view in second form

Tags: android

These picture show what I am thinking about.

[image]

```
btn_view_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                activity2 object = new activity2();
                Intent MainActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity2.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString(object.temp, "");
                MainActivity.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(MainActivity);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

here is my view cart code

[Here is my second activity. And I need to display the name, description, price, quantity and the total of all the orders whenever the user clicks the add to cart button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHYlA.png)

I need to transfer the Name, Description, Price and Quantity to a second activity using intent, and put the data in a Listview. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a link-only question without any effort by the asker to ask a proper question.

Comment: i am a new user. My apologies.

Comment: No problem, I have edited your question to at least make sure something can be seen, but we need a specific textual description of your problem as well, so please edit your question by clicking on the edit link below the android tag.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Very good! Have you tried anything so far? If so, please show us what have you tried and how did the attempt(s) fail. We also need a specific question, like: "I need to transfer the Name, Description, Price and Quantity to a second activity using intent, and put the data in a Listview. How can I achieve that?"

Comment: I have not tried anything so far, but I have made the View cart button work. The only thing I need to complete the project is when I click the "Add to Cart" button, the data of the Name, Description, Price and Quantity will be transferred to a list view in the second activity. How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: I am not an Android expert, but I can see the problems in your question. I will not give you an answer, but will help you modify this question into a state which is answerable for Android guys. If you try something, even if you fail, your question will draw more sympathy. If you show us how your View cart button was implemented, then we can see that you actually tried something. Your question in its current state will draw many down-votes and no answers. With some small changes you can raise its quality.

Comment: How can I add a picture of what I have tried so far?

Comment: You should add the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

in MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CartActivity.class)
intent.putExtra("quantity", quantity);
intent.putExtra("price", price);
intent.putExtra("description", description);
startActivity(intent);
```

in the onCreate method of CartActivity:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
double price = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("price", 0);
int quantity = getIntent().getIntExtra("quantity", 0);
```

Must use the same keys when you put and retrieve each value

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Intent`** to transfer data.

But for transfer list of data use `Bundle` and Synchronise your POJO class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use putStringArrayListExtra() and getStringArrayListExtra() to put all your orders in a list.
in you calling method:

```
ArrayList<String> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(whatever1);
        orders.add(whatever2);
        //....//
        orders.add(whateverN);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("ORDERS",orders);
```

OnCreate of the Next class add:

```
ArrayList<String> orders = Intent.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("ORDERS");
```

Comment: What should be in (whatever1)?

Comment: In your case the strings you want to add to your order list.

Comment: btn_meal3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                imgview_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mcchik);
                display_product_name.setText("Mc Chicken Meal");
                display_product_desc.setText("Best Chicken in the world");
                Double meal3_price = 49.99;

                String meal3_string_price = Double.toString(meal3_price);
                display_product_price.setText(meal3_string_price);
            }
        }); 
My code for the button 3

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this.