# .putExtra into another file

Tags: android

This is my code for the .putExtra:

```
String url = "test";
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RelationshipRemoved.class)
                    .putExtra("userInfo", urlTwo));
```

How do I call the value urlTwo in another file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the value in another `Activity` (not just another file) reading the value from the received bundle, like this:

```
String userInfo = getIntent().getStringExtra("userInfo");
```

or

```
   String userInfo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("userInfo");
```

---

Example:

`Activity` sending an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
intent.putExtra("userInfo", "abcdef123456");
startActivity(intent);
```

`ActivityTwo` receive the data stored :

```
String receivedValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("userInfo");
```

the variable `receivedValue`  will contain the string value `"abcdef123456"`.