# putExtra from activity then getExtra in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i tried to put and get extra from activity to fragment . but something is wrong! anybody have idea? my case is diffrent because i wanna do it in fragment

myActivity :

```
if(email.matches(users.user1)&&password.matches(users.pass1)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ProfileFragment.class);
        i.putExtra("pn", users.pn1);
        i.putExtra("name", users.name1);
        i.putExtra("family", users.family1);
        i.putExtra("rank", users.rank1);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

myfragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile2, container, false);

    final TextView pn =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pn);
    final TextView name =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
    final TextView family =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.family);
    final TextView user =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user);
    final TextView rank =getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rank);

    String pnget = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("pn");
    String nameget = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String familyget = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("family");
    String userget = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
    String rankget = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("rank");

    pn.setText(pnget);
    name.setText(nameget);
    family.setText(familyget);
    user.setText(userget);
    rank.setText(rankget);
}
```

Hi . i tried to put and get extra from activity to fragment . but something is wrong! anybody have idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Comment: but my case is diffrent . i wanna put and get extra from activity to fragment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** create a Fragment with startActivity. You need to create the fragment with bundle like this:

```
ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();

args.putString("name", users.name1);
args.putString("family", users.family1);
fragment.setArguments(args);

// then tell the FragmentManager to attach the fragment
// to the activity
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.your_placeholder, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Then in your `onCreateView` get them with:

```
String name = getArguments().getString("name", ""); 
String family = getArguments().getString("family", "");
```

---

Please remember that you need to move the return code to the last of `onCreateView` method and change your code to something like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile2, container, false);

   TextView pn =view.findViewById(R.id.pn);
   ...

   return view;
}
```

Comment: What is the your_placeholder ?

Comment: the fragment container view in your activity layout.

Comment: Please visit the documentation of fragment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: but i dont know how to replace with my own? :(

Comment: How do you add the fragment to your activity? Please add your layout activity to your question.

Comment: activity_main or content_main ?

Comment: Is the content_main where you want to add the fragment? Add it if yes.

Comment: there is one id and is : fragment_frame but when put in R.id.fragment_frame  fragment has chanched to red underline .:(

Comment: every thing seems ok . and if fix above problem ... your answer has correct answer

Comment: Congratulations! Please accept this answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You start an intent call intent. But the intent have data is i, and it have't started yet.

You can use setArgument and getArgument to send and receive data from activity to fragment or from fragment to fragment:

In YourReceiveFragment:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String data1, String data2, ...) {
    Fragment f = new YourReceiveFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(DATA_RECEIVE1, data1);
    bundle.putString(DATA_RECEIVE2, data2);
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}
```

In your activity: Just call it:

```
Fragment f = YourReceiveFragment.newInstance(yourString1, yourString2);

                            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.add(R.id.main_container, f).commit();
```

Then in YourReceiveFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null){
        String dataReceive1 = getArguments().getString(DATA_RECEIVE1);
        String dataReceive2 = getArguments().getString(DATA_RECEIVE2);
    }
}
```

In case you want to send data from an activity to a fragment in another activity,  use interface or an easier way is just pass the data to the activity which contains fragment and from that, send data to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data with the bundle, that is recommended

To Pass Data from Activity

```
fragment = new YourFragment();

if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key", "value");

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
}
```

To receive data from Fragment

```
  String var = getArguments().getString("value");
```