# GetStringExtra always return null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried to send string from onclick recyclerview to the activity, all doing well except one of this.

```
GeneralItem generalItem   = (GeneralItem) consolidatedList.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailPengumuman.class);

                    intent.putExtra("getnama", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getNama_p().toString());
                    Log.e("untaging","ada isinya : "+generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getNama_p().toString());

                    intent.putExtra("tanggalpengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getTanggal_peng());
                    intent.putExtra("judulpengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getJudul());
                    intent.putExtra("deskripsipengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getDeskripsi());
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I also tried to log getnama in untaging tag its doing well and return me the data in log. But when I retrieve it in another activity, It always return null.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
        tanggalPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("tanggalpengumuman");
        judulPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("judulpengumuman");
        namaPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("getnama");
        deskripsiPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("deskripsipengumuman");

        Log.e("untaging","nama : " +namaMatkulGet);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved thanks,
This because of I missing the String attribute

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        tanggalPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("tanggalpengumuman");
        judulPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("judulpengumuman");
        namaPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("getnama");
        deskripsiPengumumanGet = intent.getStringExtra("deskripsipengumuman");

        Log.e("untaging","nama : " +namaMatkulGet);
```

I receiving extra in namaPengumumanGet and I log another String which is namaMatkkulGet

Answer (score 1):

You can first check for if intent contains data or not..

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("Key")) {
            String value = bundle.getString("Key");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying Adding **.toString()** to call getStringExtra :

```
 intent.putExtra("tanggalpengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getTanggal_peng().toString());
 intent.putExtra("judulpengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getJudul().toString());
 intent.putExtra("deskripsipengumuman", generalItem.getDaftarPengumuman().getDeskripsi().toString);
```

Comment: The code demonstrated is `putExtra()`. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @Doomsknight to call getStringExtra() we have to use putExtra() with toString() value