# How to show data in a fragment which comes from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have created an activity which contains a button, a `ViewPager` and some fragments. When I click on the button a `DialogActivity` opens and connects to the web service using `AsyncHttpClient` and returns some strings which are pictures url, name, etc. to `MainActivity`. I want `MainActivity` to show the data in fragment specially the picture url (using Glide) but I can’t do this.
I appreciate it if you help me

**DialogActivity**:

```
void parsAndShowBiography(String response) {
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TheaudiodbBiography theaudiodbBiography = gson.fromJson(response, TheaudiodbBiography.class);
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent(DialogActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        returnIntent.putExtra("artistThumb", theaudiodbBiography.getArtists()
                .get(0).getStrArtistThumb());
        returnIntent.putExtra("strArtist", theaudiodbBiography.getArtists()
                .get(0).getStrArtist());
        returnIntent.putExtra("artistFanart1", theaudiodbBiography.getArtists()
                .get(0).getStrArtistFanart());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        finish();
```

**MainActivity** :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        ???????????????????????

    }
```

And this is the **Fragment** :

```
public class BiographyFragment extends Fragment {


static BiographyFragment instance;


public static BiographyFragment getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new BiographyFragment();
    }


    return instance;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bigraphy_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

I put some TextViews and ImageViews into Fragment xml file.

and if it helps this is the UX :

[image]

Comment: You need to getExtra. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233898/5885018

Comment: i want to put them into a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i solved the question with this code :

MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        View test=BiographyFragment.getInstance().getView();

        Glide.with(this).load(data.getStringExtra("artistFanart1")).into(
                            (ImageView)test.findViewById(R.id.artistFanart1));

    }
```