# I'm using Android Studio to create an app. The situation i met is I trying to using the image from another activity

Tags: android

The app's idea is solving the question by memorise the images. I have done the majoriti code but i met a situation is I trying to using the image from another activity.

This is the code for MainActivity. I'm setting a timer for memorise the polygon as the 6 img given.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView Text1;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageView imageView2;
    public ImageView imageView3;
    public ImageView imageView4;
    public ImageView imageView5;
    public ImageView imageView6;
    Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView5 = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageView6 = findViewById(R.id.imageView6);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Question1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```

The code below is second activity.I'm trying to fixed that code which is at "imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));

```
public class Question1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView Question1;
    private Button ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5, ans6, next;

    private String Right_Answer;
    private int Right_Answer_Count;
    private int quizCount = 1;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String quizData[][] = {
            {"heptagon","triangle","quadrilateral","pentagon","hexagon","decagon"}
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

        Question1 = findViewById(R.id.Question1);
        ans1 = findViewById(R.id.ans1);
        ans2 = findViewById(R.id.ans2);
        ans3 = findViewById(R.id.ans3);
        ans4 = findViewById(R.id.ans4);
        ans5 = findViewById(R.id.ans5);
        ans6 = findViewById(R.id.ans6);
        next = findViewById(R.id.next);

        for (int i=0; i < quizData.length; i++){
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]);
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]);
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]);
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]);
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]);
                tmpArray.add(quizData[i][5]);

                quizArray.add(tmpArray);
            }

            Show_Next_Quiz();
        }

        public void Show_Next_Quiz(){

            Random random = new Random();
            int Random_Num = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

            ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(Random_Num);

            imageView.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            imageView2.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            imageView3.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            imageView4.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            imageView5.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            imageView6.setImageResource(
                    getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable",getPackageName()));
            Right_Answer = quiz.get(1);

            Collections.shuffle(quiz);

            ans1.setText(quiz.get(0));
            ans2.setText(quiz.get(1));
            ans3.setText(quiz.get(2));
            ans4.setText(quiz.get(3));
            ans5.setText(quiz.get(4));
            ans6.setText(quiz.get(5));

            quizArray.remove(Random_Num);

    }

    public void Check_Answer(View view) {

        Button Answer = findViewById(view.getId());
        String btnText = Answer.getText().toString();

        String alertTitle;

        if (btnText.equals(Right_Answer)){
            alertTitle = "Correct !!!";
            Right_Answer_Count++;
        }   else    {
            alertTitle = "Sorry, you are wrong =(";
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
        builder.setMessage("Answer : " + Right_Answer);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                if (quizArray.size() < 1){
                    Show_Result();
                }   else {
                    quizCount++;
                    Show_Next_Quiz();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void Show_Result(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Result");
        builder.setMessage(Right_Answer_Count + " / 10");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again?", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                recreate();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Hence, I don't know how to let the second activity to using the image from MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass through the resource ID of the image as an Intent extra:

[How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)

Comment: Owhh i have done study the link you give me. It is useful to me! But i got question for the intent send data and receive data. It need the data type but i dun know the type for the image.

Comment: A resource ID is an int. You can only pass certain data types as intent extras, but an int is one of them.

Comment: Owhhh ok. I solve my problem already. Thank you for your reply. =)