# Android app with buttons: Is necessary one webView per button?

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a simple app, with 6 buttons and a background.
I need that buttons to open a webView inside the app, each one with a different URL. None of the examples I've found solve my question.
Is possible to do this with just a webView Class, or do I need one webView Class per button?

If you can provide any examples I'll be very gratefull.

I get this splash when pushing the button after your recommendation, Emad.

[on running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fl8l.png)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.roomssalomons2019">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoapp"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fondoapp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/but_obra" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/but_prnr" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/but_doc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="@string/but_mto" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/but_rcpcn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/but_limpieza" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.roomssalomons2019;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private Button button2;
    private Button button3;
    private Button button4;
    private Button button5;
    private Button button6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //String[] perm = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET};
        //requestPermissions(perm,0);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URl","https://roomssalomons.wixsite.com/roomssalomons/obra");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }



}
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
package com.example.roomssalomons2019;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("https://roomssalomons.wixsite.com/roomssalomons/obra");

    }

}
```

**webview.xml**

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

I don't understand the problem... ¿Can anybody help?

Thank you very much.

Eduardo A.

Comment: It's too broad...

Answer (score 0):

You can create one activity with webview , when click on any button just open this activity and pass url int it

on your button action

```
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebVIEWActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URl","YOUR_URL");
        startActivity(intent);
```

on your WebviewActivity

```
String url=getIntent().getExtras().getString("URl");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do it with one activity that contains a web view.
2. Pass the web view url through the intent set string extra method like that: [How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)