# value not passed from one activity to Main

Tags: android

I am trying to pass Latitude and Longitude from one activity to the main activity.
In MainActivity, I have defined

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  public double Lat;
  public double Long;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+Lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and using an Intent to transfer the values from another activity (**AuxActivity**) as:

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new CityListAdapter.ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
        City city =adapter.getCityAtPosition(position);
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//            city.getCity()+"\n"+city.getLatitude()+"\n"+city.getLongitude(),
//            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Double Lat = city.getLatitude();
        Double Long = city.getLongitude();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.putExtra("Lat", Lat);
        mainIntent.putExtra("Long", Long);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
      }
```

and Lat is always `0.0` in `MainActivity`, but correct value is given in `AuxActivity`'s `Toast`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: first you  check data type pass  in   you  case  double   pass  then  receive  in getIntent().getDoubleExtra("Lat",0.0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice, you aren't calling the intent values that you are passing in. You would need something like this:

```
long lat = intent.getLongExtra("LAT");
```

This would get the intent's long extra being passed into it. Look at this post for further instruction:

[How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android)